# Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2

Tags: json, powershell, depth, convertto-json

Why do I get unexpected [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) results, why do I get values like `System.Collections.Hashtable` and/or why does a round-trip (`$Json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json`) fail?

### Meta issue

Stackoverflow has a good mechanism to prevent duplicate **questions** but as far as I can see there is no mechanism to prevent questions that have a duplicate **cause**. Take this question as a an example: almost every week a new question comes in with the same cause, yet it is often difficult to define it as a duplicate because the question itself is just a slightly different.
Nevertheless, I wouldn't be surprised if this question/answer itself ends up as a duplicate (or off-topic) but unfortunately stackoverflow has no possibility to [write an article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161064/writing-article-instead-of-asking-question) to prevent other programmers from continuing writing questions caused by this “known” pitfall.

### Duplicates

A few examples of similar questions with the same common cause:

- [PowerShell ConvertTo-Json does not convert Array as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562942/powershell-convertto-json-does-not-convert-array-as-expected)
  (yesterday)
- [Powershell ConvertTo-json with embedded hashtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17929494/powershell-convertto-json-with-embedded-hashtable)
- [powershell “ConvertTo-Json” has messed json format output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53287346/powershell-convertto-json-has-messed-json-format-output)
- [Nested arrays and ConvertTo-Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929633/nested-arrays-and-convertto-json)
- [Powershell ConvertTo-JSON missing nested level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22260343/powershell-convertto-json-missing-nested-level)
- [How to save a JSON object to a file using Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275724/how-to-save-a-json-object-to-a-file-using-powershell)
- [Cannot convert PSCustomObjects within array back to JSON correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38742767/cannot-convert-pscustomobjects-within-array-back-to-json-correctly)
- [ConvertTo-Json flattens arrays over 3 levels deep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448161/convertto-json-flattens-arrays-over-3-levels-deep)
- [Add an array of objects to a PSObject at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562763/add-an-array-of-objects-to-a-psobject-at-once)
- [Why does ConvertTo-Json drop values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53354665/why-does-convertto-json-drop-values)
- [How to round-trip this JSON to PSObject and back in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32774889/how-to-round-trip-this-json-to-psobject-and-back-in-powershell)
- [Issue with ConvertFrom-Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036938/issue-with-convertfrom-json#comment135806914_77036938)
- …

### Different

So, were does this “self-answered” question differ from the above duplicates?
It has the common cause in the title and with that it might better prevent repeating questions due to the same cause.

Comment: I had the same issue. It got me asking though what GOOD comes out of the -Depth parameter? It seems to cause so much confusion...

Comment: @Omglolyes This is adressed in the top rated answer, essentially objects can be self referencing, creating an infinite loop if you tried to go to "maximum" depth.

Comment: I think that you can add [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123767/a-passing-problem-with-pscustomobject-when-passing-from-powershell-to-windows-po) to the list.

Comment: I get this error when I define a powershell custom object that has a child object, and I've forgotten the @ before that child object opening brace.

Comment: @Chris, `@{...}` defines one or more key-value pairs, where `{...}` defines an expression which (when evaluated at runtime) might result in a pretty complex object depending on the content.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

### Answer

[`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-6) has a **`-Depth`** parameter:

> Specifies how many levels of contained objects are included in the
>   JSON representation.
>   The **default** value is **2**.

### Example

To do a full round-trip with a JSON file you need to increase the `-Depth` for the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet:

```
$Json | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
```

### TL;DR

Probably because `ConvertTo-Json` terminates branches that are deeper than the default `-Depth` (**2**) with a (.Net) full type name, programmers assume a bug or a cmdlet limitation and do not read the help or about.
Personally, I think a string with a simple [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) (three dots: …) at the end of the cut off branch, would have a clearer meaning (see also: Github issue: [8381](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8381))

### Why?

This issue often ends up in another discussion as well: ***Why is the depth limited at all?***

Some objects have circular references, meaning that a child object could refer to a parent (or one of its grandparents) causing a infinitive loop if it would be serialized to JSON.

Take for example the following hash table with a `parent` property that refers to the object itself:

```
$Test = @{Guid = New-Guid}
$Test.Parent = $Test
```

If you execute: `$Test | ConvertTo-Json` it will conveniently stop at a depth level of 2 by default:

```
{
    "Guid":  "a274d017-5188-4d91-b960-023c06159dcc",
    "Parent":  {
                   "Guid":  "a274d017-5188-4d91-b960-023c06159dcc",
                   "Parent":  {
                                  "Guid":  "a274d017-5188-4d91-b960-023c06159dcc",
                                  "Parent":  "System.Collections.Hashtable"
                              }
               }
}
```

This is why it is not a good idea to automatically set the `-Depth` to a large amount.

Comment: Although, since circular dependencies are not supported in JSON, writing a serializer that does not support circular dependencies seems the more natural choice over one that only walks to a certain depth. All major JSON serializers *other than* the one in PowerShell do this. I'd call it "poor design decision" instead of "necessity".

Comment: Powershell 7.1 will give a warning.  "Emit warning if ConvertTo-Json exceeds -Depth value (#13692)"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-71?view=powershell-7.1

Answer (score 19):

*Update*: **PowerShell 7.1 introduced a *warning* when truncation occurs**. While that is better than the *quiet* truncation that occurred in earlier versions, the solution suggested below seems much preferable to me.

---

Your helpful question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583678/45375) clearly illustrate how much of a pain point the current default `ConvertTo-Json` behavior is.

**As for the *justification* of the behavior:**

While `-Depth` can be useful to *intentionally* truncate an input object tree whose full depth you don't need, **`-Depth` *defaulting* to `2` and *quietly truncating* the output amounts to *quiet de-facto failure* of the serialization from the unsuspecting user's perspective** - failure that may not be discovered until later.

**The seemingly arbitrary and quiet truncation is surprising to most users, and having to account for it in every `ConvertTo-Json` call is an unnecessary burden.**

I've created [GitHub issue #8393](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8393) containing a ***proposal* to change the current behavior, specifically as follows**:

- **Ignore `-Depth` for `[pscustomobject]` object graphs (a hierarchy of what are conceptually DTOs (data-transfer objects, "property bags"), such as returned from `Convert*From*-Json`), specifically.**

  - By contrast, **it *does* make sense to have an automatic depth limit for *arbitrary .NET types***, as they can be object graphs of excessive depths and may even contain circular references; e.g., `Get-ChildItem | ConvertTo-Json` can get quickly out of hand, with `-Depth` values as low as `4`. That said, **it is generally ill-advised to use arbitrary .NET types with JSON serialization**: JSON is *not* designed to be a general-purpose serialization format for a given platform's types; instead, it is focused on DTOs, comprising *properties* only, with a *limited set set of data types*.
  - Note that nested *collections*, including hashtables, are not themselves subject to the depth limit only their (scalar) *elements*.
  - **This distinction between DTOs and other types is, in fact, employed by PowerShell itself *behind the scenes*, namely in the context of serialization for *remoting* and *background jobs***.
- Use of `-Depth` is then only needed to *intentionally* truncate the input object tree at the specified depth (or, mostly hypothetically, in order to serialize to a deeper level than the internal maximum-depth limit, `100`).

Comment: This Depth parameter deserves the WTF of the year award. That GitHub issue is just completely sad. How can people argue for the sensibility of this behavior? It's OBVIOUSLY wrong and they "fixed" it with a warning. Haha! Optimizing for the edge case as per usual with powershell.

Answer (score 1):

`.. | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | ..`

The max depth is 100 in latest PowerShell (mine: 7.3.4, renamed from PowerShell Core).

Comment: to convert JSON to pretty-printed JSON see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133115/195755 (this answer used there)