# How to compare JSON in powershell

Tags: powershell, mulesoft

I have a requirement where I need to compare JSON object from a file to the JSON message which comes into Anypoint MQ queue. I am able to get the message from the queue. I have used below script but it is not working. I did both `-eq` and `Compare-Object` but they are not working.

```
$po_ps_output = $filemessagecontent | ConvertFrom-Json
$po_python_output = $mqmessagecontent.body | ConvertFrom-Json
$result = $po_ps_output -eq $po_python_output
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**If you just want to know *if* the two JSON-originated objects differ**, without needing to know *how*:

```bsh
$contentEqual = ($po_ps_output | ConvertTo-Json -Compress) -eq 
                ($po_python_output | ConvertTo-Json -Compress)
```

Note:

- `ConvertTo-Json` defaults to a serialization depth of `2` - use `-Depth <n>` if your data is more deeply nested to avoid truncation (potentiall data loss) - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).
- Converting back to JSON may seem like an unnecessary step, but the `-Compress` standardizes the output formatting to a single line with no extra whitespace, which ensures that incidental variations in formatting in the input (if you had used the input JSON text directly) are ignored.

---

**If you want to know *how* the two JSON-originated objects differ**:

Note: The following is **only useful in the following, *limited* scenario** -
a generic, robust solution would require much more effort:

- The inputs have the *same structure* and differ only in property names / values.
- The *ordering* of (equivalent) properties is the same.

```bsh
Compare-Object (($po_ps_output | ConvertTo-Json) -split '\r?\n') `
               (($po_python_output | ConvertTo-Json) -split '\r?\n')
```

The output will show the lines that differ, each representing a single property or primitive value; e.g.:

```
InputObject                   SideIndicator
-----------                   -------------
      "DOB":  "12-03-1994"    =>
      "DOB":  "12-03-1999"    <=
```

Note:

- `=>` / `<=` indicate that the line is unique to the RHS / LHS.
- Again, the explicit reconversion to JSON is done to ensure uniform formatting; in this case, a line-oriented pretty-printed format that enables property-by-property comparison.
- Again, you may have to use `-Depth` to prevent truncation of data.
- For *interactive* inspection of differences, you can try a difference-visualization tool, such as the one built into Visual Studio Code, by passing the two JSON strings in pretty-printed form via files to 
  `code --diff <file1> <file2>`.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`ConvertFrom-Json` creates `[pscustomobject]` instances, so you're comparing two instances of that type:

- If you use `-eq`, *reference equality* is tested for, because `[pscustomobject]` is a reference type and doesn't implement custom equality comparison.

  - Therefore, `$po_ps_output -eq $po_python_output` will only be `$true` if the two variables point to the *very same object in memory* - which is clearly not the case here, so you'll always get `$false`.
- If you use `Compare-Object`, the two instances are compared by their `.ToString()` values.

  - As of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.4, regrettably, calling `.ToString()` on an instance of `[pscustomobject]` yields the *empty string* (`''`), which should be considered a bug - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).
  - Therefore, `Compare-Object $po_ps_output $po_python_output` (unhelpfully) considers the two instances *equal* and returns nothing, since equal objects are by default not output (use `-IncludeEqual` to include them).