# PowerShell ConvertTo-JSON with multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, convertto-json

I'm trying to convert data to JSON as input for a REST API. The challenge I have is that the data should consist of multiple depths (For a lack of better words). The code I'm using now is:

```
(@{name = "Contoso"; all_assets = "false"; all_users="false"; rules= @{type="fqdn"; operator="match"; terms=@("contoso") } }| ConvertTo-Json)
```

the output now is:

```
{
    "all_users":  "false",
    "name":  "Contoso",
    "all_assets":  "false",
    "rules":  {
                  "operator":  "match",
                  "terms":  [
                                "contoso"
                            ],
                  "type":  "fqdn"
              }
}
```

The REST-Api is complaining that the data contains invalid characters. Looking at the output, the section "rules:" contains { } instead of [ ]. I've been trying all kinds of tricks but I can't seem to figure this one out.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583677/unexpected-convertto-json-results-answer-it-has-a-default-depth-of-2)

Answer (score 4):

If you want `rules` to contain an array of objects instead of an object with properties, enclose everything that goes inside the `rules` with `@()`.

Because `terms` then becomes the 3rd level, you need to add parameter `-Depth` to the ConvertTo-Json cmdlet:

<sup>For better readability, I didn't do this as one-liner</sup>

```
@{ 
   name       = "Contoso"
   all_assets = "false"
   all_users  = "false"
   rules      = @(
                   @{
                      type     = "fqdn"
                      operator = "match"
                      terms    = @("contoso")
                   }
                )
} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

Output:

> ```
> {
>     "all_users":  "false",
>     "name":  "Contoso",
>     "all_assets":  "false",
>     "rules":  [
>                   {
>                       "operator":  "match",
>                       "terms":  [
>                                     "contoso"
>                                 ],
>                       "type":  "fqdn"
>                   }
>               ]
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks Theo! The code example you gave seems to be giving the correct output. However, When using it with the Invoke-RestMethod, i'm still getting the following error:

{"error":"Invalid JSON: unexpected character at line: 1, column: 11"}

No Idea what could be wrong here. I've compared the example json data that Tenable has on their API access site and it looks exactly the same.

Comment: @MichaelWaterman Strange indeed... What happens if you send the json commpressed? For that use `ConvertTo-Json  -Depth 3 -Compress`

Comment: The same error message. I did some testing. If I create a variable $body with the exact same code that originally comes after the -Body, replace the original code with the variable $body, it works. I would almost suspect a timing issue here.

Comment: @MichaelWaterman You didn't show how you are calling the `Invoke-RestMethod` using the json as body. Storing it inside a variable always makes sure the json is complete, but otherwise, you could put the code inside round brackets to ensure the same. (Storing it in a variable first wil make the code more readable IMO)

Comment: I've come to that conclusion as well. Thanks for the help Theo, appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth...
Not the answer to the [Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/1701026) issue, but how you might generally build a PowerShell expression from a `Json` file using [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression) cmdlet:

```
'{
    "all_users":  "false",
    "name":  "Contoso",
    "all_assets":  "false",
    "rules":  [
                  {
                      "operator":  "match",
                      "terms":  [
                                    "contoso"
                                ],
                      "type":  "fqdn"
                  }
              ]
}' | ConvertFrom-Json | ConvertTo-Expression

[pscustomobject]@{
        'all_users' = 'false'
        'name' = 'Contoso'
        'all_assets' = 'false'
        'rules' = ,[pscustomobject]@{
                'operator' = 'match'
                'terms' = ,'contoso'
                'type' = 'fqdn'
        }
}
```