# Is the object empty?

Tags: powershell

I'm using an Azure API > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20request%20query/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

I'm using this code:

```
$body = @"
{
    "queries": [{
        "items": [
            "59c1c31397b266116ff6d735e5638ef5d1b598a0"
        ],
        "type": "commit"
    }]
}
"@ 

$x = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $someLink -Headers @{Authorization = $pat } -Body $body -Method Post -ContentType 'application/json'
Write-Host $x
Write-Host $x | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host $x.results | ConvertFrom-Json
```

I've removed the link for security reasons.

When I run the code I get the following in my console:

> 2020-01-20T16:17:55.8600905Z @{queries=System.Object[]; results=System.Object[]}
>
> 2020-01-20T16:17:55.8637026Z @{queries=System.Object[]; results=System.Object[]}
>
> 2020-01-20T16:17:55.8674193Z

I'm not sure if the `queries` and `results` objects are empty or that I need some other way of reading them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `Write-Host` writes to the *host* (which is typically the console / terminal), bypassing PowerShell's success output stream, which is why a command such as `Write-Host $x | ConvertFrom-Json` is pointless, because `ConvertFrom-Json` will receive *no input*.
- `Write-Host` writes *simple `.ToString()` stringifications* of non-string input objects to the host, which means that you don't get PowerShell's rich, human-friendly output formatting that implicit output or - rarely needed - explicit `Write-Output` calls result in *when ultimately printing to the host by default*, due to the output neither getting captured in a variable or getting redirected with `>`).
- `Invoke-RestMethod` *automatically* parses the JSON output it receives into PowerShell *custom objects* (`[pscustomobject]` instances, so there is also also no *conceptual* reason to pipe its property values to `ConvertFrom-Json` - unless the API truly returns *nested JSON text* as *string values* in the JSON it returns.

---

If you want to visually inspect the results, simply output them *directly*:

```bsh
$x  # output visualization of the whole object
$x.results  # just the .results property
```

The above outputs to the success output stream, which means that an outside caller of your code would receive these values as part of the code's output.

If the resulting table- or list-like formatting (depending on the number of properties) doesn't tell you enough, you can convert the objects *back* to JSON, by piping to `ConvertTo-Json`.
Note that the latter's default serialization depth is limited to 2, so you may have to pass a higher `-Depth` value to see the object in full - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).

```bsh
$x | ConvertTo-Json  # use -Depth <n>, if needed.
$x.results | ConvertTo-Json
```

If you really want to just print the values as *information for the user*, without becoming part of the output, use `Out-Host` rather than `Write-Host`, because `Out-Host` *does* apply the rich formatting:

```bsh
$x | Out-Host # print visualization of the whole object directly to the host
$x.results | Out-Host  # just the .results property

# Ditto via ConvertTo-Json
$x | ConvertTo-Json | Out-Host
...
```