# ConvertTo-Json in object with array as property value

Tags: json, sql-server, powershell, convertto-json

In Windows Powershell I have a simple `Invoke-SqlCmd` query which returns the following table:

```
ID Text
-- ----
 1 FOO 
 2 BAR 
 3 SPAM
```

Piping it to `| ConvertTo-Json -Depth 1` yields the following result:

```
[
    {
        "RowError":  "",
        "RowState":  1,
        "Table":  "",
        "ItemArray":  "1 FOO",
        "HasErrors":  false,
        "ID":  1,
        "Text":  "FOO"
    },
    {
        "RowError":  "",
        "RowState":  1,
        "Table":  "",
        "ItemArray":  "2 BAR",
        "HasErrors":  false,
        "ID":  2,
        "Text":  "BAR"
    },
    {
        "RowError":  "",
        "RowState":  1,
        "Table":  "",
        "ItemArray":  "3 SPAM",
        "HasErrors":  false,
        "ID":  3,
        "Text":  "SPAM"
    }
]
```

My desired output would be not this bare array, but an **object** having a single **property** having "Products" as name and the array as value.

Besides, I'd like my array entries being objecs having just the columns of the SQL table as properties.

That is, my desired output would be:

```
{
    "Products": [
        {
            "ID": 1,
            "Text": "FOO"
        },
        {
            "ID": 2,
            "Text": "BAR"
        },
        {
            "ID": 3,
            "Text": "SPAM"
        }
    ]
}
```

How can I achieve it?

---

EDIT: The query and its result from SQL Server Management Studio are the following:
[image: Query and result in SSMS]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$queryResult` contains the result of your `Invoke-SqlCmd` call:

```
[pscustomobject] @{ 
  Products = @($queryResult | Select-Object ID, Text)
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

- [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) creates `[pscustomobject]` instances that contain the properties representing actual table columns only, hard-coded in this case.

  - Note: Determining these column names *dynamically* makes for a more generic solution - see next section.
- `@()`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), ensures that the result is treated as an array (in case your query happens to return just *one* row).
- `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` is syntactic sugar for creating the wrapper `[pscustomobject]` instance, whose only property, `Products`, contains the array of column-values-only objects.
- `ConvertTo-Json` converts the resulting custom object back to JSON.

  - While not an issue here, do note that recursion depth is limited to *2* by default, necessitating explicit use of `-Depth` to prevent data loss - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).

---

#### Determining the column names dynamically:

<sup>[Mathias R. Jessen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712649/mathias-r-jessen), assisted by [Fry Simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4579181/fry-simpson), worked out this solution.</sup>

By making the [`Invoke-SqlCmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd#outputs) call return a `System.Data.Table` instance
via `-OutputAs DataTables`, `.Column.ColumnNames` can be used to extract the query's column names as an array:

```
# Note the use of `-OutputAs DataTables`; `-As DataTables` should work too.
$queryResult = Invoke-SqlCmd -OutputAs DataTables -Query "SELECT * FROM Schema1.dbo.Table_1" -ServerInstance $instanceName -Database $databaseName  

[pscustomobject] @{ 
  Products = @($queryResult | Select-Object $queryResult.Columns.ColumnName) 
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

By default, `Invovke-SqlCmd` returns a stream of individual `System.Data.DataRow` instances.

Note how using even when `$queryResult` contains a `System.Data.DataTable` instance, its *rows* are implicitly sent through the pipeline; in other words: `$queryResult | ...` is the same as `$queryResult.Rows | ...`, which is behavior built into PowerShell.