# ConvertTo-JSON falsely parses arrays

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, data-conversion

This question has also been answered here:

[Stackoverflow: Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/11508928)

[GitHub: ConvertFrom-Json and ConvertTo-Json breaks arrays](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5604#issuecomment-348612367)

[Mircrosoft Docs: ConvertTo-JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json?view=powershell-5.1#parameters)

TL;DR

If you save your .json with `ConvertTo-JSON` and it break it, you may want to speccify the `-Depth` parameter, as it's default value it 2 and it wont parse nestet objects beyond that.

Original Post:

So I want to load, then save  data from a JSON file through a PowerShell skript. The JSON contains an array within an object, which looks like this:

```
{
    "head": {
        "head2": {
            "data0": "a",
            "data1": "b"
        },
        "head3": {
            "data8": [
                "x",
                "y",
                "z"
            ],
            "data9": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the array "data8".

Now when I load and save the file like so: `Get-Content test.json | ConvertFrom-JSON | ConvertTo-JSON` I want to end up with the exact same file, since I'm not changing anything. However the result is this:

```
{
    "head": {
        "head2": {
            "data0": "a",
            "data1": "b"
        },
        "head3": {
            "data8": "x y z",
            "data9": "hello"
        }
    }
}
```

The "data8" has been reduced to a single string and I struggle to find out why. It seems to happen during the `ConvertTo-JSON` because when I don't do that yet, It will give me an array of strings containing x,y and z.

E.g. `(Get-Content test.json | ConvertFrom-JSON).head.head3.data8` will result in

> x
>
> y
>
> z

and `(Get-Content test.json | ConvertFrom-JSON).head.head3.data8 -is [array]` gives `True`

Things I've tried:(get-content test.json | convertfrom-json).head.head3.data8

Various encoding methods in test.json, but this even happens when I save the file as utf8 and add `-encoding utf8` to `Get-Content` so I don't believe that is has to do with that.

For the sake of trying, I even added `-compress` to `ConvertTo-JSON` which didn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so apparently PowerShell only [parses data up to a depth of 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json?view=powershell-5.1#parameters) by default. So as pointed out [Here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5604#issuecomment-348612367) you have to specify the depth with the `depth` prameter of `ConvertTo-Json`