# PowerShell Array, adding new records where one property is an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I am unable to use ArrayList or avoid using `+=` for array manipulation. Wishing that powerShell had a universal add or append available.

I have the below JSON array for `$aksAppRules.RulesText`

```
    [{
    "Name": "A2B",
    "Description": null,
    "SourceAddresses": [
      "10.124.176.0/21",
      "10.124.184.0/21"
    ],
    "TargetFqdns": [
      "*.github.com",
      "*.grafana.com",
      "*.trafficmanager.net",
      "*.loganalytics.io",
      "*.applicationinsights.io",
      "*.azurecr.io",
      "*.debian.org"
    ],
    "FqdnTags": [],
    "Protocols": [
      {
        "ProtocolType": "Https",
        "Port": 443
      }
    ],
    "SourceIpGroups": []
  },
  {
    "Name": "Y2office365",
    "Description": null,
    "SourceAddresses": [
      "10.124.176.0/21",
      "10.124.184.0/21"
    ],
    "TargetFqdns": [
      "smtp.office365.com"
    ],
    "FqdnTags": [],
    "Protocols": [
      {
        "ProtocolType": "Http",
        "Port": 25
      },
      {
        "ProtocolType": "Http",
        "Port": 587
      }
    ],
    "SourceIpGroups": []
  }
]
```

I managed to make this work with the below powershell snippet

```bsh
$new_list = @()
$collectionRules = $aksAppRules.RulesText | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($rule in $collectionRules) {
    $protoArray = @()
    ForEach ($protocol in $rule.Protocols) {
        $protoArray += $protocol.ProtocolType + "," + $protocol.Port
    
    }
    #$new_list += , @($rule.Name, $rule.SourceAddresses, $rule.TargetFqdns, $protoArray )
    # the 'comma' right after += in below line tells powershell to add new record. 
    $new_list += , @{Name=$rule.Name;SourceAddresses=$rule.SourceAddresses; TargetFqdns=$rule.TargetFqdns;Protocol=$protoArray}
}
$new_list | ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json | select Name, SourceAddresses, TargetFqdns, Protocol| Convert-OutputForCSV -OutputPropertyType Comma | Export-Csv .\test.csv
```

The CSV looks like

---

[image: Output-formattedin Excel]

I am unable to do this using `Arraylists` and without using += as I heard it is inefficient with large arrays.

I have to copy things to a new array because I have to change the key:value format of the original "Protocols" to a 2 d array.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should [avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60708578/1701026) as it exponential expensive. Instead you should use the pipeline

```
collectionRules = $aksAppRules.RulesText | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($rule in $collectionRules) {
    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name = $rule.Name
        SourceAddresses = $rule.SourceAddresses
        TargetFqdns = $rule.TargetFqdns
        Protocol = @(
            ForEach ($protocol in $rule.Protocols) {
                $protocol.ProtocolType + "," + $protocol.Port
            }
        )
    }
} | Convert-OutputForCSV -OutputPropertyType Comma | Export-Csv .\test.csv
```

<sub>***Note 1***: I have no clue why you are doing `| ConvertTo-Json | ConvertFrom-Json`, so far I can see there is no need for this if you use a `[pscustomobject]` rather than a `[Hashtabe]` type.</sub>

<sub>***Note 2***: I no clue what the function `Convert-OutputForCSV` is doing and suspect that isn't required either (but left it in).</sub>

Comment: ConvertTo-Json|ConverFrom-json -- that worked for me.. don't remember reason. However the convert-OutputForCSV is a special function I found to workaround the issue of "system.object" that shows up...  I went to modifying this using sed/printf and JQ using linux. I liked the "Properties" thing in powershell initially, but find that it is misleading and basic things like not writing the output value to an export is tiresome to keep up.

Comment: @user587585, the  `"system.object"` is probably caused by the default depth of `ConvertTo-Json`. See:[Unexpected ConvertTo-Json results? Answer: it has a default -Depth of 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/1701026).