# Call API inside powershell function

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-4.0, invoke-restmethod

How to call API inside function. this is my url  https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json. I am new for powershell can you help me to do this.

```
function Holiday {
 
   $list = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json
   Write-Host "$list"

}
```

but i am unable to list . can u please help me on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) automatically parses the API's JSON response into an object [graph]** - a nested `[pscustomobject]` instance or an array thereof (in a manner of speaking, `Invoke-RestMethod` has [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) built in).

While very **convenient for subsequent OO *processing***, the resulting objects' ***display representation* isn't very helpful**:

- Only the *top-level properties* of the object graph are printed.
- Due to a long-standing bug - see [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163) - nested property values may falsely appear to be empty - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74023166/45375) for an example.

**To quickly *visualize* the result**, you can simply **convert *back to JSON***, using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```bash
function Get-Holiday {
 
  # Call the API, which returns JSON that is parsed into a [pscustomobject]
  # graph, and return (output) the result.
  Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri https://www.gov.uk/bank-holidays.json

}

$list = Get-Holiday

# Visualize the object for display by converting it back to JSON.
$list | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3
```

- Note the **unfortunate need to specify `-Depth 3`** explicitly - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375) for background information.

An **alternative visualization** can be achieved by piping to **[`Format-Custom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-custom)**:

- The resulting for-display representation isn't JSON, but a notation that resembles hashtable literals and is easy to parse visually.
- `Format-Custom`'s default depth is 5 (compared to `ConvertTo-Json`'s 2), so you will often get away *without* a `-Depth` argument.
- Conversely, however, you may need to (temporarily) set the [`$FormatEnumerationLimit` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#formatenumerationlimit) to ensure that all elements of a *collection* are visualized; by default, only *4* are, and omitted elements are represented as `…`.
  That said, if you just want to get a quick sense of the *structure* of the object graph, that may not be a problem.

```bash
# Assumes that $list was obtained as above.
$list | Format-Custom
```

Output (showing just the *first* object; note the `…` indicating that the collection contained in the `.events` property has additional elements that were omitted):

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  england-and-wales =
    class PSCustomObject
    {
      division = england-and-wales
      events =
        [
          class PSCustomObject
          {
            title = New Year’s Day
            date = 2018-01-01
            notes =
            bunting = True
          }
          class PSCustomObject
          {
            title = Good Friday
            date = 2018-03-30
            notes =
            bunting = False
          }
          class PSCustomObject
          {
            title = Easter Monday
            date = 2018-04-02
            notes =
            bunting = True
          }
          class PSCustomObject
          {
            title = Early May bank holiday
            date = 2018-05-07
            notes =
            bunting = True
          }
          …
        ]

    }
```

---

With respect to *processing*, here's an example that accesses the first entry for England and Wales:

```bash
$list.'england-and-wales'.events[0]
```

The above yields:

```
title          date       notes bunting
-----          ----       ----- -------
New Year’s Day 2015-01-01          True
```

Comment: `JSON` parsing in powershell is done this way?  is this methodology specific to `JSON`?

Comment: Hi, i need to get date value from all objects like english-and-wales, scotland , northern ireland. using this $list.'england-and-wales'.events.date i will get only england-and-wales details but remaining scotland, northern ireland date i am unable to fetch

Comment: @NicholasSaunders: `ConvertFrom-Json` and `Invoke-RestMethod` (with JSON responses) parse the JSON into an object model using `[pscustomobject]`, and you can access that object model with regular dot notation.

Comment: @AFFISHMOHAMMAD: `$list.scotland.events[0]` and `$list.'northern-ireland'.events[0]` Again, if you need further assistance, II encourage you to ask a _new_ question.