# Extract data from API (odata) into file (csv or json) - Powershell

Tags: powershell, odata, invoke-restmethod

I am new here, I have to extract data from api web (odata I think) into a file (I don't manage the api data source)
I try to extract with the following code

```
Invoke-RestMethode -Uri https://myapi.com/api/listofservers -UseDefaultCredentials - Out-File "path"
```

I try to fetch from Excel (Power Query) just to test too but I have the same result (below)

| @odata.context | value |
| --- | --- |
| https://myapi.com:portsnumber/api/$metadata#listofservers | {@{Id=1234; Name;Description;Serverpath;Date |

Sorry for these poor of information, I am not an expert of Shell (or any code). I try searching some post with my problems, I didn't find any.

Could you help me on this please (or give some tips ?)

Regards,

Comment: Your problem my simply be a _display_ problem - see if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819321/45375) helps.

Comment: What... is your question? What are you hoping to extract?