# A passing problem with PSCustomObject when passing from PowerShell to Windows PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-core

I'm trying to setup an IIS application pool via PowerShell 7.1.1.

I read configuration from a JSON file into the variable `$configuration` which is hand over to Windows Powershell because of `WebAdministration` module which isn't natively supported PS 7.1.1.

A script block is defined in the top level function, the configuration is injected as `PSCustomObject` into the script block and executed in Windows PowerShell.

```
function Set-AxisAppPool
{
    Write-Message 'Setting up a resource pool for Axis...'
    $executeInWindowsPowerShellForCompatibilityReasons = {
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory)]
            [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
            [PSCustomObject]
            $Configuration
        )

        Import-Module WebAdministration
        Remove-WebAppPool -Name $Configuration.AppPool.Name -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
        New-WebAppPool -Name $Configuration.AppPool.Name -Force | Write-Verbose

        $params = @{
            Path  = "IIS:\AppPools\$($Configuration.AppPool.Name)"
            Name  = 'processModel'
            Value = @{
                userName     = $Configuration.AxisUser.Name
                password     = $Configuration.AxisUser.Password
                identitytype = 'SpecificUser'
            }
        }
        Set-ItemProperty @params
    }
    powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile $executeInWindowsPowerShellForCompatibilityReasons -Args $configuration # This is a line 546
}
```

When the configuration JSON file exceeds a certain level, PowerShell can't pass through this deserialized JSON, the `PSCustomObject`, into Windows PowerShell.

```
 Program 'powershell.exe' failed to run: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to use environment
     | variables.At C:\Users\JohnDoe\Desktop\Localhost automatization\Set-AxisEnvironment.ps1:546 char:5 +     powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile
     | $executeInWindowsPowerShellForCompa … +
```

It literally work with level `n` of objects in the JSON and it doesn't with `n+1` level of objects in the configuration JSON. The JSON schema is validated, deserialization works as expected.

When I use `Start-Process` for invoking Windows PowerShell, I receive a different problem. Does anybody have any hint on this one?

### Update

This seems to be a bug in [PowerShell](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14775).

Comment: Try running ProcMon to see what is executed actually. I thing your `-Args $configuration` is serialized some way, and it it trimmed some way.

Comment: @filimonic Done, but I'm not sure what I'm looking for... Many events related to .NET, CLR etc. anything suspicious.

Comment: Take a look at toolbar and find a `windows flag` button. Un-press other buttons in group (reg, file, net, prof). Now enable `Filter -> Drop filtered events`. Look for `Process Create` operations. Exclude trash ( RBClick -> Exclude <...> )

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it is the size of the argument list overflowing into other fields, thus giving you weird error messages. From [Start Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=net-5.0#remarks):

> The length of the string assigned to the [Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.arguments?view=net-5.0#remarks) property must
> be less than 32,699.

If you are passing a configuration that is larger than 32,699 characters (including spaces), then that likely may be your problem. It would likely take those first 32,699 characters then continue to the next field, `-UseShellExecute` which would receive a character which is not `zero` or `false`, and thus `true`. This would trip the "wrong", and misleading error message.

Comment: I've updated my question with a link to PowerShell issue. The JSON does not exceeds 32 699 characters (it has about 14 000).