# How to expand environmental variables in JSON into valid JSON notation by PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

This question relates to my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123767/a-passing-problem-with-pscustomobject-when-passing-from-powershell-to-windows-po) and to this [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14775).

When I try to read a configuration from a JSON which contains an environmental variable, e.g. `%USERPROFILE%\\source` an obvious choice `[System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($jsonString)` expands the JSON string into non-valid JSON notation, e.g. "C:\Users\JohnDoe". The `\U` is not a valid JSON notation.

**The question is how to overcome this problem** (*with some clean code*).

Comment: Do you mean the single backslashed should be doubled? then try `"C:\Users\JohnDoe" -replace '\\', '\\'` or `"C:\Users\JohnDoe".Replace("\","\\")`

Comment: Yes, exactly. Unfortunately, simple text substitution can't be used.

Comment: Why not? You set up a splatting Hashtable in your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66123767/a-passing-problem-with-pscustomobject-when-passing-from-powershell-to-windows-po), so it would be easy enough to to the replacement there: `[System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($jsonString)  -replace '\\', '\\'`

Comment: Because there are UNC in the JSON and other stuff. I would have to make even more substitutions to fix all the false-positive. I made a function which substitutes environment variables only in the JSON raw string. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve my issue with PowerShell (the issue listed in the question).

Answer (score 0):

If you are performing the replacement on the entire `$jsonString` then, yes,
`$jsonString -replace '\\', '\\'` will replace too many backslashes.

You could then beter do this instead:

```
$match = ([regex] '(%([^%]+)%)').Match($jsonString)
while ($match.Success) {
    $search     = $match.Groups[1].Value
    $replace    = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($match.Groups[2].Value) -replace '\\', '\\'
    $jsonString = $jsonString -replace $search, $replace
    $match      = $match.NextMatch()
}
```

This will only replace the matched `%SomeVar%` environment variables by what they expand into doubles all possible backslashes in that.

Test using some bogus JSON:

```
$jsonString = @"
{
    "Name": "%USERNAME%",
    "UserPath": "%USERPROFILE%\\source"
    "WinDir": "%SystemRoot%"
    "InetPath": "%SystemDrive%\\inetpub\\wwwroot",
}
"@
    $match = ([regex] '(%([^%]+)%)').Match($jsonString)
    while ($match.Success) {
        $search     = $match.Groups[1].Value
        $replace    = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable($match.Groups[2].Value) -replace '\\', '\\'
        Write-Host $search
        write-host $replace
        $jsonString = $jsonString -replace $search, $replace
        $match      = $match.NextMatch()
    } 

$jsonString
```

Output:

```
{
    "Name": "KUTlime",
    "UserPath": "C:\\Users\\KUTlime\\source"
    "WinDir": "C:\\WINDOWS"
    "InetPath": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In is general a bad practice to peek and poke into [serialized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) object strings (as e.g. a `Json` and `XML`) using string methods like `Replace`. Instead it is better to de-serialize the string to an object, make your changes, and serialize it to a string again. This way you prevent pitfalls along with incorrectly replacing a backslash with a special meaning (such as an escape for a double quote or a Unicode character).
As it might be a hassle to recursively craw through a complex object to expand all the strings, I have written a small function for this:

```
function Expand-String {
    [CmdletBinding()] param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeLine = $True)]$Object
    )
    Process {
        if ($Object -is [string]) { $Object = [System.Environment]::ExpandEnvironmentVariables($Object) }
        elseif ($Object -is [Collections.IDictionary]) {
            Foreach ($Key in @($Object.get_Keys())) { $Object[$Key] = Expand-String $Object[$Key] }
        }
        elseif ($Object -is [Collections.IEnumerable]) { 
            for ($i = 0; $i -lt $Object.Count; $i++) { $Object[$i] = Expand-String $Object[$i] }
        }
        else {
            Foreach ($Name in ($Object.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object { $_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty' }).Name) {
                $Object.$Name = Expand-String $Object.$Name
            }
        }
        $Object
    }
}
```

```
$Json = @'
{
    "Environment Variables": {
        "Name": "%USERNAME%",
        "UserPath": "%USERPROFILE%\\source",
        "WinDir": "%SystemRoot%",
        "InetPath": "%SystemDrive%\\inetpub\\wwwroot"
    },
    "Special  Characters": {
        "Quote": "Hello \"World\"",
        "Unicode": ["\u1F60A", "\u1F44D"]
    }
}
'@

$Object = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json | Expand-String
$Object.'Environment Variables'

Name    UserPath                WinDir     InetPath
----    --------                ------     --------
KUTlime C:\Users\KUTlime\source C:\WINDOWS C:\inetpub\wwwroot
```

```
$Json = $Object | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9
$Json

{
  "Environment Variables": {
    "Name": "KUTlime",
    "UserPath": "C:\\Users\\KUTlime\\source",
    "WinDir": "C:\\WINDOWS",
    "InetPath": "C:\\inetpub\\wwwroot"
  },
  "Special  Characters": {
    "Quote": "Hello \"World\"",
    "Unicode": [
      "ὠA",
      "ὄD"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: This approach seems to be more reasonable to me. Unfortunately for me, it doesn't solve my original problem.