# Obtain full result in the output of Powershell Script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script to obtain query result. The problem is I can't obtain all the result in the output when I run the script. I have 3 little points that probably means the result continue. See on the image.

How can I obtain all results when I run the script ?
[image]

Comment: Please consider marking one of the answers as the solution...

Answer (score 1):

Since we don't know what the structure of the output object of the script looks like, it's really hard to tell what option is the best way to visualize the output.

`| ConvertTo-Json` is one way.

But if the output is a flat structure I would go with `| Format-List *`

Answer (score 0):

You're using [`Format-Custom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-custom) to *visualize* a data structure (as with all `Format-*` cmdlets, `Format-Custom`'s purpose is to create a representation *for the human observer*, not for programmatic processing).

`Format-Custom` respects the - rarely used - [`$FormatEnumerationLimit` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#formatenumerationlimit) , which defaults to `4` and specifies the maximum number of elements of an *array*-valued property to display, with additional, omitted elements represented as `...`

Therefore, the immediate solution to your problem is to **set `$FormatEnumerationLimit` to a large enough value, to ensure that *all* array elements render**:

```sh
# Use a large enough value to ensure that *all* elements are shown.
$FormatEnumerationLimit = [int]::MaxValue

# A simplified example of outputting an object with an array-valued property
[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1..5 } | Format-Custom
```

Note: It's worth saving the old `$FormatEnumerationLimit` value and restoring it afterwards; *normally*, you could achieve this effect more conveniently by placing both commands inside `& { ... }`, so as to create a local, transient copy of the variable, but due to a *bug* - still present as of PowerShell 7.2 - that doesn't work in this particular case - see [GitHub issue #888](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/888#issuecomment-321955184).

The above yields the following, showing that all `5` elements - more than the default limit of `4` - are shown:

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  foo = 
    [
      1
      2
      3
      4
      5
    ]
    
}
```

---

**Alternatively**, you can **use [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) for quick visualization**, which - as a *data*-processing cmdlet - isn't subject to the `$FormatEnumerationLimit` limit:

```sh
[pscustomobject] @{ foo = 1..5 } | ConvertTo-Json # add -Depth as needed.
```

**Pitfall**: `ConvertTo-Json` limits its recursion depth to `2`, which means that more deeply nested data structures won't be shown in full - use the `-Depth` parameter as needed to prevent truncation - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375) for more information.

The above yields:

```
{
  "foo": [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
  ]
}
```