# Different results from Invoke-WebRequest and Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, azure-rest-api, invoke-webrequest, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to call Azure Rest API and get Schedules of DevTestLabs. I tried Invoke-RestMethod, but it doesn't give **value** on **"dailyRecurrence"** key. But Invoke-WebRequest does.

What would be the reason for that?

**URL**

```
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourseGroup}/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/{LabName}/schedules/LabVmsShutdown?api-version=2018-10-15-preview"
```

**URL with $expand**

```
$url = "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionID}/resourceGroups/{resourseGroup}/providers/Microsoft.DevTestLab/labs/{LabName}/schedules/LabVmsShutdown?$expand=properties(dailyRecurrence)&api-version=2018-10-15-preview"
```

**Calling Invoke-RestMethod**

```
$output = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method "GET" -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $authHeaders

properties : @{status=Enabled; taskType=LabVmsShutdownTask; dailyRecurrence=; timeZoneId=AUS Eastern Standard Time;
         notificationSettings=; createdDate=26/03/2019 4:38:18 PM; provisioningState=Succeeded;
         uniqueIdentifier=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}
```

**Calling Invoke-WebRequest**

```
$output = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Method "GET" -Headers $authHeaders

Content           : {"properties":{"status":"Enabled","taskType":"LabVmsShutdownTask","dailyRecurrence":{"time":"1900"}
                ,"timeZoneId":"AUS Eastern Standard Time","notificationSettings":{"status":"Disabled","timeInMinute
                s":30},"createdDate":"2019-03-26T03:38:18.0726376+00:00","provisioningState":"Succeeded","uniqueIde
                ntifier":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},"id":"/subscriptions/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/resourcegroups/XXXXXXXXXXXXX/providers/microsoft.devtestlab/labs/XXXXXXXX/schedules/labvmsshutdown","name":"LabVmsShutdown","type":"microsoft.devtestlab/labs/schedules","location":"australiasoutheast"}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem:

- is merely a *display* problem,
- albeit one that exposes a long-standing *bug*, still present as of PowerShell Core 7.3.3, namely that `[pscustomobject]` instances mistakenly stringify to the *empty string* - see [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163).

In short:

- The data *is* there in the [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) output, it just *appears* to be missing - see the next section.
- Use `$output.properties.dailyRecurrence` to see it or, to more helpfully visualize the output, use it `$output |` [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) to re-convert it to (prettified) JSON.

  - Note: Situationally, you may have to add a `-Depth` argument to fully represent object graphs with a depth greater than 2 - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).

---

[`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) - unlike [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) - has *deserialization built in*: with a JSON response, it automatically parses the JSON text returned into a `[pscustomobject]` graph as if [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) had been applied to it.

You're seeing the default formatting of the resulting object graph, which isn't really suited to visualizing *nested* `[pscustomobject]` instances, which are represented by their `.ToString()` values - and therefore - due to the bug - may *appear* to have no value, even when they do.

By contrast, since the output from `Invoke-WebRequest` reports the JSON text as-is in the `.Content` property of its output objects, the problem doesn't surface there.

A simple demonstration of the bug:

```bash
[pscustomobject] @{ 
  nested = 
    [pscustomobject] @{ 
      deep = 
        [pscustomobject] @{ 
          deepest = 'down'
        } 
    } 
}
```

As of PowerShell Core 7.3.3, this yields the following, mistakenly suggesting that `.nested.deep` has no value, even though it clearly does:

```
nested
------
@{deep=}
```