# Adding a Property to JSON with Powershell

Tags: json, powershell

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here?  I am trying to add additional properties to an existing JSON file.

This is my existing JSON File:

```
{
  "filePath": "F:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\XXXX\\Services\\file.exe",
  "Services": {
    "BBBBBB": {
      "Id": "BBBBBB",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {}
    },
    "XXXX1Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX1Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "XXXX2Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX2Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "Application Tier URL": {
          "Value": "my.com"
        },
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "XXXX3Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX3Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "XXXX4Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX4Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to insert properties to make it look like this (look under XXX3Service):

```
{
  "filePath": "F:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\XXXX\\Services\\file.exe",
  "Services": {
    "BBBBBB": {
      "Id": "BBBBBB",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {}
    },
    "XXXX1Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX1Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "XXXX2Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX2Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "Application Tier URL": {
          "Value": "my.com"
        },
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        }
      }
    },
    "XXXX3Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX3Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        },
        "XXX 3 Service": {
          "Enabled": true
        },
        "My Token": {
          "Value": "1234567890"
        },
        "Authority": {
          "Value": "authority.com"
        },
        "ThisSecret": {
          "Value": "1234-1234-1234-1234"
        }
      }
    },
    "XXXX4Service": {
      "Id": "XXXX4Service",
      "Installed": true,
      "OverrideValues": {
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My Code looks like this:

```
# Get json content from a file
$json = Get-Content .\source.json

# convert the json to be a powershell object
$psObject = $json | ConvertFrom-Json

# useful for referencing to see all of the properties
# $psObject.Services | Select-Object *
# $psObject.Services.XXXX3Service
# $psObject.Services.XXXX3Service.OverrideValues

#* ConvertTo-Json the max allowed depth is 100
$newProperty = @"
{
    "OverrideValues": {
        "HostName": {
          "Enabled": true,
          "Value": "my.com"
        },
        "XXX 3 Service": {
          "Enabled": true
        },
        "My Token": {
          "Value": "1234567890"
        },
        "Authority": {
          "Value": "authority.com"
        },
        "ThisSecret": {
          "Value": "1234-1234-1234-1234"
        }
      }
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 100

# get the name to overwrite the existing property so it's not nested
$propName = $newProperty.PSObject.Properties | Select-Object -Expand Name

# here we supply the $propname value in json as well as use the value(s) under the $newProperty to overwrite the existing property
$psObject.Services.XXXX3Service | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $propName -Value $newProperty.$propName -Force

# lastly convert and export the json
$psObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 | Out-File "C:\temp\good.json"
```

however I am getting the following errors:

```
ConvertFrom-Json : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Depth'.
At C:\Users\user\Downloads\json.ps1:38 char:23
+ "@ | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 100
+                       ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Add-Member : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
At C:\Users\user\Downloads\json.ps1:44 char:77
+ ... Service | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $propName -Value  ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Member], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddMemberCo
   mmand
```

Comment: What version of powershell are you using? The `-Depth` parameter for `ConvertFrom-Json` was only added in newer versions than the default installed 5.1

Comment: I am using 5.1.17763.2867.  I have not had an issues using Depth in other attempts I have tried.

Answer (score 2):

**tl;dr**

- Remove `-Depth 100` from your `ConvertFrom-Json` call.
- With `ConvertFrom-Json`, use of `-Depth` is *generally not needed*, and in *Windows PowerShell* that parameter doesn't even *exist* (whereas it *does* for the complementary cmdlet, `ConvertTo-Json`, where it is *often needed*).

---

- As [Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale) points out, in *Windows PowerShell* the [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json?view=powershell-5.1) - note the *From* - does *not* have a `-Depth` parameter. It exists in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, where, however, it is  *rarely needed*.

  - Despite the parameter having the same name as `ConvertTo-Json`'s (see below), it functions very differently: It is used to enforce that the input JSON isn't more deeply nested than the given `-Depth` value, and reports an *error* if it is.
  - As [zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out, the default value is `1024`, so only more deeply nested JSON would cause an error - which seems unlikely. However, you *can* use `-Depth` to *increase* that limit, up to `2,147,483,647` (`[int]::MaxValue`), at least formally.
- By contrast, [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) - note the *To* - does have this parameter in Windows PowerShell too, and, unfortunately, it is *frequently needed*:

  - By default, PowerShell limits the serialization depth to *two* levels of recursion, necessitating an explicit `-Depth` argument to properly serialize more deeply nested object graphs - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375). Absent that, if the default serialization depth is exceeded, *quiet truncation* occurs in Windows PowerShell, whereas in PowerShell (Core) you now at least get a *warning*.