# Failed to convert parameter value from a PSObject to a Byte[] (PowerShell)

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am attempting to insert some data into a azure sql database using powershell. I am a powershell beginner.  The data I am inserting comes from a json file.

The data I am trying to insert is:
(1)Property1 of the json which is a string.
(2)Property2 of the json which is a string .
(3) the entire content of the json file as a string.

However I'm getting this error:

Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Failed to convert parameter value from a PSObject to a Byte[]."

If I try to use: $Command.Parameters["@JsonContent"].Value = $jsonContent.ToString() - Then I get an empty/blank string inserted into the table

This is my code: Please could you help me see the problem

```
$Connection = New-Object System.Data.SQLClient.SQLConnection
$Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$server;Database=$database;User 
ID=$username;Password=$password;Trusted_Connection=False;"

if($Connection.State -eq 'Closed')
{
  $Connection.Open()
}
else 
{
  $Connection.Open()
}


$insertStatement = "INSERT INTO $table (P1, P2, JsonContent) 
VALUES (@P1, @P2, @JsonContent)"


$Command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($insertStatement, $Connection)
$Command.Parameters.Add("@P1", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 250)
$Command.Parameters.Add("@P2", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::VarChar, 250)
$Command.Parameters.Add("@JsonContent", [System.Data.SqlDbType]::NVarChar, -1)

Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesPath -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
$jsonContent = Get-Content $_.FullName | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 100

# Set the parameter values for the SQL insert statement
$Command.Parameters["@P1"].Value = $jsonContent.P1
$Command.Parameters["@P2"].Value = $jsonContent.P2
$Command.Parameters["@JsonContent"].Value = $jsonContent


# Execute SQL insert statement
$Command.CommandText = $insertStatement
$Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

# Output the filename to the pipeline log
Write-Host "Inserted $($_.FullName) into $table"
}


$Connection.Close()
```

The table I am trying to insert into is defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dev].[TestTable]
(
[P1] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
[P2] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
[JsonContent] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
[JsonHash]  AS (hashbytes('SHA2_256',[JsonContent])) PERSISTED,
CONSTRAINT [pkTestTable] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[P1] ASC
)WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) 
ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not solve *all* your problems, but let me address an obvious one:

- You're reading `*.json` files, so it makes no sense to pipe them to [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertTo-Json); perhaps you meant [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Json) [*update*: you've since changed to `ConvertFrom-Json` in your question], i.e. perhaps your intent is to parse the JSON text *into an object graph* - which is the prerequisite for being able to access properties `.P1` and `.P2`

So perhaps this is what you meant:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Path $jsonFilesPath -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
  
  # Read the JSON text as a single, multi-line string
  $jsonText = $_ | Get-Content -Raw

  # Parse the JSON text into an object graph, so you can access properties.
  $objectGraphFromJson = $jsonText | ConvertFrom-Json
  
  # Set the parameter values for the SQL insert statement
  $Command.Parameters["@P1"].Value = $objectGraphFromJson.P1
  $Command.Parameters["@P2"].Value = $objectGraphFromJson.P2
  $Command.Parameters["@JsonContent"].Value = $jsonText
  
  # Execute SQL insert statement
  $Command.CommandText = $insertStatement
  $Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
  
  # Output the filename to the pipeline log
  Write-Host "Inserted $($_.FullName) into $table"
}
```

Note:

- It is `$jsonText`, i.e. the original JSON *string* that is assigned to the `JsonContent` SQL parameter.

  - Note that with your own code, once you changed to `ConvertFrom-Json`, you would have assigned a `[pscustomobject]` a.k.a `[psobject]` instance instead (the *object graph* that JSON was parsed into), which would explain the symptom.
- As an aside re your use of the `-Depth` parameter:

  - There is usually no need for `-Depth` when *reading* JSON (`ConvertFrom-Json` - except if your JSON has more than 1024(!) nesting levels).
  - However, `-Depth` *is* important when *writing* JSON (`ConvertTo-Json`), because the default depth is then, unfortunately, 2. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660856/45375) for more information.