# How do I read a JSON HashTable as a HashTable in Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell

```
# foo.json
{
 'foo': {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2
  }
}
```

```
$foo = Get-Content 'foo.json' | ConvertFrom-Json -Depth 30
$foo.a
1
$foo.b
2
$foo['a']
Error
```

How do I read in the JSON hash table as an actual hash table in powershell?

Alternatively, how do I enforce this in a reasonable manner in a hardcoded fashion, as this seems to be non-trivial?

Answer (score 1):

[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) parses the following JSON:

```json
{
 'foo': {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2
  }
}
```

into a (nested) `[pscustomobject]` instance equivalent to the following *literal*:

```bash
[pscustomobject] @{
  foo = [pscustomobject] @{
    a = 1
    b =  2
  }
}
```

The name of the *variable* that you use to capture the result, `$foo = ...` is *incidental*; what matters are the *properties* of the intrinsically *unnamed* `[pscustomobject]` instance.

Therefore:

```bash
$var = @'
{
  'foo': {
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2
   }
 }
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json # no need for -Depth

$var.foo.a # -> 1
$var.foo.b # -> 2
```

That is, you must access the `foo` *property* of the (itself unnamed) `[pscustomobject]` instance stored in variable `$var`, so you can access the nested `a` / `b` properties .

---

In **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, you indeed now have the option to return a nested *hashtable* instead, via the **`-AsHashTable`** switch, allowing you to use *index* notation (`['foo']`) - though note that PowerShell allows you to use dot notation (`.foo`) with hashtables too:

```bash
# PowerShell 7+
# -AsHashTable returns a (nested) hashtable instead.
$var = @'
{
  'foo': {
   'a': 1,
   'b': 2
   }
 }
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json -AsHashtable

# Hashtables can be accessed with either index or dot notation.
$var.foo.a # -> 1
$var['foo']['b'] # -> 2
```

---

Note:

- Hashtables ([`System.Collections.Hashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable)) are more light-weight than `[pscustomobject]` instances, so, if you're using PowerShell (Core) 7+, `-AsHashTable` is worth considering, if feasible for subsequent use.

  - In PowerShell 7.3+, a new type *derived* from `System.Collections.Hashtable` is returned, which preserves the *input order* of the properties.
- The `-Depth` parameter is generally only needed for the *inverse* cmdlet, [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json), i.e. for *generating* JSON rather than for *parsing* it - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660856/45375).