# Uploading a text file to discord using webhook

Tags: powershell, discord, webhooks, invoke-webrequest

I looked through and tested a few examples I saw online with no success.
From what I understand it should look something like the code below:

```
$hookUrl = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

$Body = @{
  'username' = $env:username
  'content' = "this is a test"
  "file=@C:\Users\User\Desktop\test.txt"
}



Invoke-WebRequest -uri $hookUrl -Method POST -Body $Body -Headers @{'Content-Type' = 'application/json'}
```

ERRORS

```
Invoke-WebRequest : {"code": 50109, "message": "The request body contains invalid JSON."}
At line:11 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -uri $hookUrl -Method POST -Body $Body -Headers @{' ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

I have seen a few extensively long methods to achieve this in the documentation, however if you see below I will post a one liner that accomplishes what I want using CMD. Is it really this simple in CMD but in powershell it takes 15+ lines?

```
curl -F "payload_json={\"username\": \"jakoby\", \"content\": \"download me\"}" -F "file=@\"C:\Users\User\Desktop\newUser.txt\"" WEB-HOOK
```

Comment: Please add details that describe the actual problem. What happens and what do you expect to happen. Also add any error messages.

Comment: edited to add errors recieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Update*:

- The answer below (next section) addresses the original form of your question.
- It later emerged that you're looking for the PowerShell equivalent of a `curl` command line that uses a `multipart/form-data` submission to submit both JSON and upload a local file.

  - [Example 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#example-6-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission) in the [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest) help topic shows you how to do that, but it is more verbose than the `curl` command.
  - The simplest solution may therefore be to simply call your `curl` command from PowerShell, but be sure to use `curl.exe` to unambiguously target the *external executable*, not the `curl` *alias* for `Invoke-WebRequest` that is built into Windows PowerShell  (it has been removed in PowerShell (Core) 7+).

    ```
    # In PowerShell 7.3+, the "\" chars. are *no longer necessary*.
    curl.exe -F "payload_json={\`"username\`": \`"jakoby\`", \`"content\`": \`"download me\`"}" -F "file=@\`"C:\Users\User\Desktop\newUser.txt\`"" WEB-HOOK
    ```

    - Note the unfortunate need to escape the embedded `"` *twice*:

      - Once, with `` ` ``, to satisfy PowerShell's syntax requirements for double-quoted strings (as expected).

        - You could obviate the need for this if you used `'...'` for the overall quoting, but that would preclude embedding variable values directly in the string.
      - [*Update*: No longer necessary in v7.3+ - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59036879/45375)] Unexpectedly *again*, with `\`, to work around a long-standing bug with respect to passing arguments containing verbatim `"` chars. to external programs.

---

Since the target web service expects *JSON*, you must convert your `$Body` *hashtable* to JSON before passing it to [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)'s `-Body` parameter, which you can do with [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```
Invoke-WebRequest -uri $hookUrl -Method POST -Body (ConvertTo-Json $Body) -Headers @{'Content-Type' = 'application/json'}
```

The obligatory *general caveat*: with more deeply nested objects, you may need to pass a `-Depth` argument to `ConvertTo-Json` to prevent accidental truncation of data - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).

---

It seems that you also want to upload a *local file*:

- Since the web service has no access to your local file system, passing a *local file path* as part of your JSON cannot work - the local file's *content* must be uploaded.
- The `Invoke-WebRequest` docs only discuss uploading local files in the context of `multipart/form-data` submissions - see [example 6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#example-6-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission), for instance.