# Powershell Invoke-RestMethod : body content is not interpreted correctly when send PUT Request

Tags: json, powershell, methods, pscustomobject, invoke-restmethod

I have built a PUT Request using Invoke-RestMethod in a powershell script.

This request looks like :

```
# Main global var
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $pat -AsPlainText
$credential = [PSCredential]::new($username, $securePassword)
$organization = "myorganization"
$project = "myproject"
$username = "username"
$pat = "myRandomPatFromAzureDevOps"
# AZDO build env var
$buildNumber = "test1.0"
# AZDO Wiki global vars
$page = "Release-Notes-$buildNumber"

$Body = [PsCustomObject]@{ 
    "content" = "$results"
} | ConvertTo-Json 

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/MyWiki.wiki/pages?path=$page&api-version=7.0" -Method 'PUT' -Authentication Basic -Credential $credential -Headers $headers -Body $Body
```

As we can see on the azure devops rest api in order to add content in the wiki repository [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/create-or-update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP), in order to update the wiki I have to give in the Request **Body** a parameter named **[content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/create-or-update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#request-body)** into string format.

This the content of my var `$results` pass to the `content` parameter :

```
|Id|AreaPath|IterationPath|WorkItemType|State|Title|CloseDate|
|---------|---------------|--------------------|-------------------|------------|------------|--------------------------------|
|8888|Parts Unlimited Team|Parts Unlimited Sprint 2023-03|Bug|Closed|Parts Unlimited Sprint log security password|03-03-2023 13:31:37|
|9999|Parts Unlimited Team|Parts Unlimited Sprint 2023-03|Task|Closed|Parts Unlimited SprintAutomatisation APIs |03-01-2023 08:32:31|
```

As you can see, I am trying to pass a MarkDown table as a string.
For format the result like this I have found and used a function named ConvertTo-MarkDownTable :

```
function ConvertTo-MarkDownTable {
    [CmdletBinding()] param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)] 
        $InputObject
    )
    Begin { 
        $headersDone = $false
        $pattern = '(?<!\\)\|'  # escape every '|' unless already escaped
    }
    Process {
        if (!$headersDone) {
            $headersDone = $true
            # output the header line and below that a dashed line
            # -replace '(?<!\\)\|', '\|' escapes every '|' unless already escaped
            "`n|{0}|" -f (($_.PSObject.Properties.Name -replace $pattern, '\|') -join '|')
            "`n|{0}|" -f (($_.PSObject.Properties.Name -replace '.', '-') -join '|')
        }
        "`n|{0}|" -f (($_.PsObject.Properties.Value -replace $pattern, '\|') -join '|')
    }
}
```

The initial data in `$results` are values that I recovered from a GET Method of Azure DevOps Rest API. When I see the type of my `$results`, I have this :

```
# $results.GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Now when I run the `Invoke-RestMethod`, noting is sent in the body **content** parameter :

```
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "https://dev.azure.com/$organization/$project/_apis/wiki/wikis/MyWiki.wiki/pages?path=$page&api-version=7.0" -Method 'PUT' -Authentication Basic -Credential $credential -Headers $headers -Body $Body

Output :
path        : /path-to-push-content
order       : 1
gitItemPath : /path%2Dto%2Dcontent.md
subPages    : {}
url         : https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/id-of-event-etag/_apis/wiki/wikis/fid-of-wiki-request/pages
              /%2Fpath-to-push-content
remoteUrl   : https://dev.azure.com/myorganization/id-of-event-etag/_wiki/wikis/fid-of-wiki-request?pagePath=%
              2Fpath-to-push-content
id          : randomId
content     :
```

But I have tested this request using `POSTMAN`. And everything is working well.
This is the request :
[image]

As you can see, the results is parsed and interpreted correctly.

And this is the upload on azure devops wiki :
[image]

Why my PUT method request does not sent content in my powershell script as POSTMAN do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're passing a media type of `application/json`:

- You must pass a JSON *string* to [`Invoke-WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)'s `-Body` parameter

  - Since `$results` is an *array* of lines, you must manually join its elements with newlines to form a single, multi-line string: `` $results -join "`n" ``. If you rely on implicit stringification inside an expandable string (`"$results"`), the elements are joined with *spaces* instead.
- PowerShell will *not* automatically convert a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pscustomobject) or [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) to JSON for you.

Therefore, construct your `$Body` variable as follows, using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json):

```
$Body = @{ 
  "content" = $results -join "`n"
} | ConvertTo-Json
```

- Note how passing a *hashtable* rather than a `[pscustomobject]` is sufficient.
- A general caveat (it doesn't apply here): More deeply nested objects / hashtables may get *truncated*, unless you pass a sufficiently high `-Depth` value to `ConvertTo-Json` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).

---

Here's a self-contained example that demonstrates that a JSON string passed to `-Body` is posted correctly:

- [https://postman-echo.com/put](https://postman-echo.com) *echoes* the input JSON in the `data` property of the JSON response it returns.
- Using [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) instead of `Invoke-WebRequest` automatically parses that JSON response into a `[pscustomobject]` graph, which makes it easier to visualize the successful round trip.

```
$results = @'
|Id|AreaPath|IterationPath|WorkItemType|State|Title|CloseDate|
|---------|---------------|--------------------|-------------------|------------|------------|--------------------------------|
|8888|Parts Unlimited Team|Parts Unlimited Sprint 2023-03|Bug|Closed|Parts Unlimited Sprint log security password|03-03-2023 13:31:37|
|9999|Parts Unlimited Team|Parts Unlimited Sprint 2023-03|Task|Closed|Parts Unlimited SprintAutomatisation APIs |03-01-2023 08:32:31|
'@

$body = @{ 
  "content" = $results
} | ConvertTo-Json 

(
  Invoke-RestMethod https://postman-echo.com/put `
    -Method PUT `
    -ContentType application/json `
    -Body $body
).data |
  Format-List
```

Output, which shows that the `$results` value was properly submitted:

```
content : |Id|AreaPath|IterationPath|WorkItemType|State|Title|CloseDate|
          |---------|---------------|--------------------|-------------------|------------|------------|--------------------------------|
          |8888|Parts Unlimited Team|Parts Unlimited Sprint 2023-03|Bug|Closed|Parts Unlimited Sprint log security password|03-03-2023 13:31:37|
          |9999|Parts Unlimited Team|Parts Unlimited Sprint 2023-03|Task|Closed|Parts Unlimited SprintAutomatisation APIs |03-01-2023 08:32:31|
```

Comment: thank you, you were right. I have applied your changed and it works perfectly. You save my day :)

Comment: Glad to hear we got to the bottom of it, @french_dev; my pleasure.