# Trying to put together a rest request using invoke-request and variablegroup - update

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

**PowerShell 5.1

Azure DevOps Server 2020**

I'm trying to use PowerShell 5.1 `Invoke-RestMethod` to get/set a single variable in my Azure DevOps Library Group Variables. There's 9 other variables in the group.

The GET part works, now I just need some help with setting a variable in my library group variable. I want to set a single variable in my group that contains 9 other variables.

When I try to set it, I don't get an error but it doesn't update the variable either. It just returns data as if I did a GET.

Resources:
[Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1)
[Variablegroups - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/update?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0#variablevalue)
[Variablegroups - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/variablegroups/get-variable-groups?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP)

```
function Main{
    SetVariable
}

function GetVariables {
    $uri = 'my azure devops uri'
    $credential = SetCredentials -userId 'user1' -password 'P@$$w0rd123'
    $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $credential
    $results.value.variables
}

function SetVariable {
    $uri = 'my azure devops uri'
    $credential = SetCredentials -userId 'user1' -password 'P@$$w0rd123'

    $body = @{ aVariableInGroup = 'hello world'}

    $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Body  $body -Method Put
    $results
}

function SetCredentials ($userId, $password) {
    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force
    return New-Object -TypeName PSCredential -ArgumentList $userId, $securePassword
}

Main
```

UPDATED:

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The request indicated a Content-Type of \"\" for method type \"PUT\" 
which is not supported. Valid content types for this method are: application/json, 
application/json-patch+json.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException, 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"VssRequestContentTypeNotSupportedException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At C:\Users\user1\Documents\WIP Update Password Library Group Variables.ps1:19 char:16
+ ...  $results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Body ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

Comment: Well the "update" link provided is telling you your request method should be `PUT` so `-Method Put` should be used.

Comment: updated op  with results

Comment: Sounds like you need to add `-ContentType application/json` to your [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) call too.

Comment: As far as the body is concerned, is that how I’d address setting a single variable in a group of variables? And if I wanted to update 2 or more, just comma separate name/value pairs? The Variablegroup-Update docs didn’t have an example on how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [`Invoke-RestMethod`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) call:

- Use `-Method PUT`
- Use `-ContentType application/json` to specify the media type.
- Pass a *JSON string* to `-Body`; use [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json) to convert your [hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) to such a string; this would equally work with a [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instance.

```bash
$body = @{ aVariableInGroup = 'hello world'} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri $uri -Credential $credential -Body $body
```

Note:

- It isn't a problem with your sample input hashtable, but note that you may need `ConvertTo-Json`'s `-Depth` parameter to prevent unintended *truncation* of more deeply nested input object graphs - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).