# ConvertTo-Json appears to be hanging

Tags: powershell

The file `minimal.json` contains:

```
{
    "data":  {
                 "labels":  [
                                "GERMAN AMERICAN BANK",
                                "JOHNSON BANK",
                                "WASHINGTON TRUST BANK"
                            ],
                 "datasets":  [
                                  {
                                      "data":  [
                                                   {
                                                       "y":  43.84,
                                                       "x":  51
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                       "y":  47.02,
                                                       "x":  12
                                                   },
                                                   {
                                                       "y":  58.21,
                                                       "x":  53
                                                   }
                                               ],
                                      "label":  "data"
                                  }
                              ]
             },
    "options":  {
                    "title":  {
                                  "text":  "Banks",
                                  "display":  true
                              },
                    "scales":  {

                               },
                    "plugins":  {
                                    "datalabels":  {
                                                       "formatter": function(value, context) { var idx = context.dataIndex; return context.chart.data.labels[idx]; },
                                                       "display":  true
                                                   }
                                }
                },
    "type":  "scatter"
}
```

If I execute the following at a console:

```
@{ chart = Get-Content C:\temp\minimal.json -Raw } | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

The console appears to hang. It is unresponsive to `C-c`.

Is this a bug in `ConvertTo-Json`?

Any suggestions on how to get this example to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- Your problem is specific to *Windows PowerShell* (it no longer affects [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)).
- A solution that works in *both* editions is to cast the `Get-Content -Raw …` call to `[string]`:

```bash
@{ chart = [string] (Get-Content C:\temp\minimal.json -Raw) } | 
  ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

<sup>Note: `-Depth 100` is *not* required in this case, because the default depth, `2`, is sufficient to serialize your input hashtable (the *content* of the `chart` entry value, due to being a *string*, is irrelevant with respect to the recursion depth - leaving the undesired Windows PowerShell behavior discussed below aside).

However, *in general* it's worth paying attention to whether a `-Depth` argument is needed - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375).</sup>

---

###### Background information:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), in both PowerShell editions, decorates its `[string]` output objects with [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) properties.

  - These properties are: `PSChildName`, `PSDrive`, `PSParentPath`, `PSPath`, `PSProvider`, and `ReadCount`, and you can discover them with `Get-Content C:\temp\minimal.json -Raw | Get-Member -Type NoteProperty`).
- In *Windows PowerShell only*, these properties are *included* when these output objects are serialized via [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json).<sup>[1]</sup>

  - Serializing arbitrary .NET objects with `-Depth 100` can result in excessive amounts of data getting serialized and even potentially *infinite loops*, depending on the nature of the object - this is what you saw, due to the ETS properties being included in the serialization.
  - Casting the `Get-Content -Raw …` call to `[string]` implicitly *discards* the ETS properties, resulting in an *undecorated* `[string]` instance that serializes as just its *text*, and thereby bypasses the problem.

---

<sup>[1] [PR #15665](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/pull/15665), which took effect in PowerShell (Core) 7.2., now intentionally excludes ETS properties of types `[string]` and `[datetime]`, specifically.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a workaround:

```
$minimal = Get-Content c:\temp\minimal.json -raw

$literal = @"
$minimal
"@


$json = @{ 
    
    chart = $literal

} | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100
```

Comment: This works, because in effect it creates a new, _undecorated_ `[string]` instance. However, a simple `[string]` cast is sufficient.