# Empty API response after moving from Python to Powerhsell

Tags: python, powershell, dictionary, hashtable

I developed a bot to scrape some info via "API" in Python and now I want to change the stack to Powershell.

I'm having difficulties with one of the requests. In Python it works like a charm but on Powershell I'm unable to make it work in the same way.

In Python, I just create the payload

```
  arrayWebCodes = ["PR1234", "PR3456"]
  payloadStock={
        "productsCN[]": arrayWebCodes ,
        "productsCC[]": arrayWebCodes 
    }
  response = s.post(urlStock, data=payloadStock)
```

This is because I want to obtain info for multiples products in a single call.

When I try to implement same on Powershell, response is empty.

```
$arrayProducts = @("PR1234", "PR73456")
$payloadStock = [ordered]@{
    "productsCN[]" = $arrayProducts
    "productsCC[]" = $arrayProducts
}
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlStock -body $payloadStock -Method "POST" -WebSession $webSession
```

Somehow, Powershell Hashtables of Arrays have some differences with Python dictionary of arrays I'm trying to implement here.

If I implement the request with only one code in Powershell, it works. So if I go from:

```
$codProduct1 = "PR1234"
$codProduct2 = "PR3456"
$payloadStock = [ordered]@{
    "productsCN[]" = $codProduct1, $codProduct2
    "productsCC[]" = $codProduct1, $codProduct2
}
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlStock -body $payloadStock -Method "POST" -WebSession $webSession
```

to:

```
    $codProduct1 = "PR1234"
    $codProduct2 = "PR3456"
    $payloadStock = [ordered]@{
        "productsCN[]" = $codProduct1
        "productsCC[]" = $codProduct1
    }
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlStock -body $payloadStock -Method "POST" -WebSession $webSession
```

It Works...

I'm about to quit, any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Change From : [ordered] To: [psobject]

Comment: Same behaviour...

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using? (if this is *Windows* PowerShell, try [PowerShell 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows))

Comment: $PSVersionTable
PSVersion                      7.3.6
PSEdition                      Core

Comment: Just noticed that you doing a `POST` for Python and a `GET` for PowerShell...

Comment: Yes! Nice catch sorry for that... unfortunately same outcome!

I wish i could share more details... basically Just obtained the data from developer tools in the explorer. 

I've been playing around with it and it seems it accepts several methods... but sticking to same(POST), still empty...

Comment: Hi @iRon!!!

Changing it to POST and making a change in the URL made it work...

THANKS!

Comment: Make items an array : "productsCN[]" = @($codProduct1, $codProduct2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really the answer to your issue, but just to be sure.
This should be the same:

#### Python

```
import json

arrayWebCodes = ["PR1234", "PR3456"]
payloadStock={
    "productsCN[]": arrayWebCodes ,
    "productsCC[]": arrayWebCodes 
}
print(json.dumps(payloadStock))
```

```
{"productsCN[]": ["PR1234", "PR3456"], "productsCC[]": ["PR1234", "PR3456"]}
```

#### PowerShell

```
$arrayProducts = @("PR1234", "PR73456")
$payloadStock = [ordered]@{
    "productsCN[]" = $arrayProducts
    "productsCC[]" = $arrayProducts
}
$payloadStock | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
```

```
{"productsCN[]":["PR1234","PR73456"],"productsCC[]":["PR1234","PR73456"]}
```

I suspect that the [`Invoke-WebRequest -body`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest#-body) might have the same `-Depth` default issue as for [unexpected `ConvertTo-Json` results? Answer: it has a default `-Depth` of `2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53583678/1701026).
What happens if you provide the `-body` as a (json) string:

```
$jsonPayload = $payloadStock | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 9
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $urlStock -body $jsonPayload -Method GET -WebSession $webSession
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I also tried that. API does not seems affected by sending it in JSON string or PSObject (Did not tested on Python)

Here is the output for the convertto-json (Yes, they are the same...) Also tested in different files and with JSON parser :(

{"productsCC[]":["PR723345","PR710663"],"productsCN[]":["PR723345","PR710663"]}

Comment: Related Depth topic: I always try to do all conversions with "-depth 99" for avoiding issues. Anyway, this JSON will always have a depth of 1... but I'll dig on Invoke-WebRequest...