# Powershell-organize an array of json data into a csv using the below code, however I'm unsure to make it into the right format that I'm looking

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, csv

I'm trying to organize an array of Json data into a csv using the following code, but I'm still unsure of how to make it into the correct structure that I was seeking below.

```
$response = Invoke-RestMethod 'resturl' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers  
$response | ConvertTo-Json
$response | Export-Csv "\<path\>\\input.json" -NoTypeInformation
$properties=@('applicationServerId','applicationId','applicationName','serverName','serverFqdn','serverStatus','serverEnvironment','productLine','datacenter','serverType','serverSubStatus', @{Name='platform';Expression={$\_.platforms\[0\]}} @{Name='instance';Expression={$\_.platforms\[1\]}} @{Name='environment';Expression={$\_.platforms\[2\]}} @{Name='platformMasterId';Expression={$\_.platforms\[3\]}} @{Name='host';Expression={$\_.platforms\[4\]}} @{Name='gateway';Expression={$\_.platforms\[5\]}})
```

Expected output:

```
[
    {
        "applicationServerId":  12345,
        "applicationId":  "123456",
        "applicationName":  "my_application1",
        "serverName":  "test",
        "serverFqdn":  "test.com",
        "serverStatus":  "yes",
        "serverEnvironment":  "dev",
        "productLine":  "myproduct1",
        "datacenter":  "austn",
        "platforms":  [
                          "@{platform=myplatform1; instance=test-austn; environment=DEV; platformMasterId=12345; host=; gateway=}"
                      ],
        "serverType":  "app",
        "serverSubStatus":  null
    },
    {
        "applicationServerId":  12345,
        "applicationId":  "1234567",
        "applicationName":  "my_application2",
        "serverName":  "test",
        "serverFqdn":  "test.com",
        "serverStatus":  "yes",
        "serverEnvironment":  "Development",
        "productLine":  "myproduct2",
        "datacenter":  "austn",
        "platforms":  [
                          "@{platform=myplatform2; instance=test-austn; environment=DEV; platformMasterId=123456; host=; gateway=}"
                      ],
        "serverType":  "app",
        "serverSubStatus":  null
    }
    ]
```

I'm getting with current code in csv format: -

```
"applicationServerId","applicationId","applicationName","serverName","serverFqdn","serverStatus","serverEnvironment","productLine","datacenter","serverType","serverSubStatus","platform","instance","environment","platformMasterId","host","gateway"

"12345","123456","my_application1","test","test.com","yes","dev","myproduct1","austn","Application",,"@{platform=myplatform1; instance=test-austn; environment=DEV; platformMasterId=12345; host=; gateway=}",,,,,

"12345","123456","my_application1","test","test.com","yes","dev","myproduct1","austn","Application",,"@{platform=myplatform1; instance=test-austn; environment=DEV; platformMasterId=12345; host=; gateway=}","@{platform=myplatform2; instance=test-austn; environment=DEV;platformMasterId=12345; host=; gateway=}",,,,,
```

Looking for each array has to be assigned to group variable name - platforms and it should be in a column. how can I make it in power shell.

Comment: Please, next time, properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) your post.

Comment: Your `platform` property is converted to a `[string]` type. Please use [$response | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583677/unexpected-convertto-json-results-answer-it-has-a-default-depth-of-2) and [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77227395/edit) that to the question instead.