# How can I extract personal names from this JSON file (wiktionary dump)?

Tags: json, windows, powershell, wiktionary

[This link](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/All%20languages%20combined/by-pos-name/kaikki_dot_org-dictionary-all-by-pos-name.json) contains all 'proper names' in wiktionary in all languages. This means personal names like Tatiana, Zadie or Richard. However it also includes names of countries, towns, rivers, and so on.

I want to extract all records which are personal names.

The records I want to extract either have the string "given name" in them or the string "surname" (some have both).

For example the name Fabian:

```
{"pos": "name", "wikipedia": ["Fabian (name)"], "head_templates": [{"name": "en-proper noun", "args": {}, "expansion": "Fabian"}], "etymology_text": "From Latin Fabiānus (“belonging to Fabius”), derived from Fabius + -ānus.", "etymology_templates": [{"name": "der", "args": {"1": "en", "2": "la", "3": "Fabiānus", "4": "", "5": "belonging to Fabius"}, "expansion": "Latin Fabiānus (“belonging to Fabius”)"}, {"name": "m", "args": {"1": "la", "2": "Fabius"}, "expansion": "Fabius"}, {"name": "m", "args": {"1": "la", "2": "-ānus"}, "expansion": "-ānus"}], "sounds": [{"ipa": "/ˈfeɪbi.ən/"}, {"audio": "LL-Q1860 (eng)-Vealhurl-Fabian.wav", "text": "Audio (Southern England)", "tags": ["Southern-England"], "ogg_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/2b/LL-Q1860_%28eng%29-Vealhurl-Fabian.wav/LL-Q1860_%28eng%29-Vealhurl-Fabian.wav.ogg", "mp3_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/2/2b/LL-Q1860_%28eng%29-Vealhurl-Fabian.wav/LL-Q1860_%28eng%29-Vealhurl-Fabian.wav.mp3"}], "word": "Fabian", "lang": "English", "lang_code": "en", "senses": [{"links": [["given name", "given name"]], "raw_glosses": ["(rare) A male given name from Latin."], "glosses": ["A male given name from Latin."], "tags": ["rare"], "id": "Fabian-en-name-XC4~mcw6", "categories": [{"name": "English given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}, {"name": "English male given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Male given names", "Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}], "translations": [{"lang": "Aragonese", "code": "an", "sense": "male given name", "tags": ["masculine"], "word": "Fabián", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Catalan", "code": "ca", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabià", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Faroese", "code": "fo", "sense": "male given name", "tags": ["masculine"], "word": "Fabian", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "French", "code": "fr", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabien", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Galician", "code": "gl", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabián", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Galician", "code": "gl", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabiano", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Galician", "code": "gl", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabio", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "German", "code": "de", "sense": "male given name", "tags": ["masculine"], "word": "Fabian", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Hungarian", "code": "hu", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fábián", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Italian", "code": "it", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabiano", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Polish", "code": "pl", "sense": "male given name", "tags": ["masculine", "person"], "word": "Fabian", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Portuguese", "code": "pt", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabiano", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Spanish", "code": "es", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabián", "_dis1": "96 4"}, {"lang": "Swedish", "code": "sv", "sense": "male given name", "word": "Fabian", "_dis1": "96 4"}]}, {"links": [["surname", "surname"]], "glosses": ["A surname."], "id": "Fabian-en-name-EMUC1F3L", "categories": [{"name": "English surnames", "kind": "other", "parents": [], "source": "w"}]}]}
{"pos": "name", "head_templates": [{"name": "head", "args": {"1": "fo", "2": "proper noun", "g": "m"}, "expansion": "Fabian m"}], "inflection_templates": [{"name": "fo-decl-proper-noun-s-indef", "args": {"1": "Fabian", "2": "Fabian", "3": "Fabiani", "4": "Fabians"}}], "forms": [{"form": "", "source": "declension", "tags": ["table-tags"]}, {"form": "fo-decl-proper-noun-s-indef", "source": "declension", "tags": ["inflection-template"]}, {"form": "Fabian", "tags": ["indefinite", "nominative"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabian", "tags": ["accusative", "indefinite"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabiani", "tags": ["dative", "indefinite"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabians", "tags": ["genitive", "indefinite"], "source": "declension"}], "word": "Fabian", "lang": "Faroese", "lang_code": "fo", "senses": [{"links": [["given name", "given name"]], "glosses": ["a male given name"], "tags": ["masculine"], "id": "Fabian-fo-name-h8YdwBAs", "categories": [{"name": "Faroese given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}, {"name": "Faroese male given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Male given names", "Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}]}]}
{"pos": "name", "head_templates": [{"name": "head", "args": {"1": "de", "2": "proper noun", "g": "m"}, "expansion": "Fabian m"}], "etymology_text": "Borrowed from Latin Fabiānus (“belonging to Fabius”).", "etymology_templates": [{"name": "glossary", "args": {"1": "loanword", "2": "Borrowed"}, "expansion": "Borrowed"}, {"name": "bor", "args": {"1": "de", "2": "la", "3": "Fabiānus", "4": "", "5": "belonging to Fabius", "lit": "", "pos": "", "tr": "", "ts": "", "id": "", "sc": "", "g": "", "g2": "", "g3": "", "nocat": "", "sort": ""}, "expansion": "Latin Fabiānus (“belonging to Fabius”)"}, {"name": "bor+", "args": {"1": "de", "2": "la", "3": "Fabiānus", "4": "", "5": "belonging to Fabius"}, "expansion": "Borrowed from Latin Fabiānus (“belonging to Fabius”)"}], "sounds": [{"ipa": "/ˈfaːbian/"}, {"audio": "De-Fabian.ogg", "text": "Audio", "ogg_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/De-Fabian.ogg", "mp3_url": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/transcoded/c/c9/De-Fabian.ogg/De-Fabian.ogg.mp3"}], "word": "Fabian", "lang": "German", "lang_code": "de", "senses": [{"links": [["given name", "given name"]], "glosses": ["a male given name"], "tags": ["masculine"], "id": "Fabian-de-name-h8YdwBAs", "categories": [{"name": "German given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}, {"name": "German male given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Male given names", "Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}]}]}
{"pos": "name", "head_templates": [{"name": "head", "args": {"1": "oc", "2": "proper noun", "head": "", "g": "m", "g2": ""}, "expansion": "Fabian m"}, {"name": "oc-proper noun", "args": {"1": "m"}, "expansion": "Fabian m"}], "word": "Fabian", "lang": "Occitan", "lang_code": "oc", "senses": [{"links": [["given name", "given name"], ["Fabian", "Fabian#English"]], "raw_glosses": ["(Gascony) a male given name, equivalent to English Fabian"], "glosses": ["a male given name, equivalent to English Fabian"], "tags": ["Gascony", "masculine"], "id": "Fabian-oc-name-VtvZQ6Yw", "categories": [{"name": "Gascon", "kind": "other", "parents": [], "source": "w"}, {"name": "Occitan given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}, {"name": "Occitan male given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Male given names", "Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}]}]}
{"pos": "name", "head_templates": [{"name": "pl-proper noun", "args": {"1": "m-pr"}, "expansion": "Fabian m pers"}], "inflection_templates": [{"name": "pl-decl-noun-m-pr", "args": {"nomp": "Fabianowie"}}], "forms": [{"form": "", "source": "declension", "tags": ["table-tags"]}, {"form": "pl-decl-noun-m-pr", "source": "declension", "tags": ["inflection-template"]}, {"form": "Fabian", "tags": ["nominative", "singular"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianowie", "tags": ["nominative", "plural"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabiana", "tags": ["genitive", "singular"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianów", "tags": ["genitive", "plural"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianowi", "tags": ["dative", "singular"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianom", "tags": ["dative", "plural"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabiana", "tags": ["accusative", "singular"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianów", "tags": ["accusative", "plural"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianem", "tags": ["instrumental", "singular"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianami", "tags": ["instrumental", "plural"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianie", "tags": ["locative", "singular"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianach", "tags": ["locative", "plural"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianie", "tags": ["singular", "vocative"], "source": "declension"}, {"form": "Fabianowie", "tags": ["plural", "vocative"], "source": "declension"}], "etymology_text": "Borrowed from Latin Fabianus.", "etymology_templates": [{"name": "glossary", "args": {"1": "loanword", "2": "Borrowed"}, "expansion": "Borrowed"}, {"name": "bor", "args": {"1": "pl", "2": "la", "3": "Fabianus", "4": "", "5": "", "lit": "", "pos": "", "tr": "", "ts": "", "id": "", "sc": "", "g": "", "g2": "", "g3": "", "nocat": "", "sort": ""}, "expansion": "Latin Fabianus"}, {"name": "bor+", "args": {"1": "pl", "2": "la", "3": "Fabianus"}, "expansion": "Borrowed from Latin Fabianus"}], "sounds": [{"ipa": "/ˈfa.bjan/"}, {"rhymes": "-abjan"}], "hyphenation": ["Fa‧bian"], "word": "Fabian", "lang": "Polish", "lang_code": "pl", "senses": [{"links": [["given name", "given name"], ["Fabian", "Fabian#English"]], "glosses": ["a male given name, equivalent to English Fabian"], "tags": ["masculine", "person"], "id": "Fabian-pl-name-VtvZQ6Yw", "categories": [{"name": "Polish given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}, {"name": "Polish male given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Male given names", "Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}]}]}
{"pos": "name", "head_templates": [{"name": "head", "args": {"1": "sv", "2": "proper noun", "head": "", "g": "c", "3": "genitive", "4": "Fabians"}, "expansion": "Fabian c (genitive Fabians)"}, {"name": "sv-proper noun", "args": {"1": "c"}, "expansion": "Fabian c (genitive Fabians)"}], "forms": [{"form": "Fabians", "tags": ["genitive"]}], "word": "Fabian", "lang": "Swedish", "lang_code": "sv", "senses": [{"links": [["given name", "given name"]], "glosses": ["a male given name"], "tags": ["common-gender"], "id": "Fabian-sv-name-h8YdwBAs", "categories": [{"name": "Swedish given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}, {"name": "Swedish male given names", "kind": "topical", "parents": ["Male given names", "Given names", "Names", "All topics", "Proper nouns", "Terms by semantic function", "Fundamental", "Nouns", "Lemmas"], "source": "w"}]}]}
```

As a human I can see that *Fabian*, the first record in the file linked, goes from lines 2 to 7. Line 8 is a new record. But I can't work out a regex pattern that will allow me to extract the whole of records like *Fabian*, which are personal names.

Can you help?

Comment: You may also be interested in the cli tool https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the input data is in JSON format, it's best to parse it as such, using [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json), which allows you to filter by the properties of the JSON objects using [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object):

```bash
# Assumes that an input file named "names.json"
$personalNameObjects = 
  [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path -LiteralPath names.json)) | 
  ConvertFrom-Json | 
  Where-Object { $_.senses.links -match '(?:given |sur)name' }
```

`$personalNameObjects` now contains [`[pscustomobject]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_PSCustomObject) instances representing those input JSON objects where the `.senses.links` property values contain either `given name` or `surname` (as *substrings*, as there are variations, such as with a plural `s` or a suffix such as `#English`) - further filtering, such as by entry type, may be needed.

To get just the unique names themselves - assuming they're stored in the `.word` property - use:

```bash
$personalNameObjects | ForEach-Object word | Sort-Object -Unique
```

Note:

- Given the size of the input file (almost 1 GB), [`[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines) is used to improve reading performance; [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)  `-LiteralPath names.json` works too, but would be noticeably slower.

  - Because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's, [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) is used to pass the input file's *full* path.
- If needed, you can later convert the filtered parsed-from-JSON objects back to JSON using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json); be sure to use a sufficiently large `-Depth` argument to prevent inadvertent truncation (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375) for background).

Comment: This looks promising, but when I try to write the var to a file, PS crashes before completing. This is what I'm using, any hints? *ConvertTo-Json $personalNameObjects -Depth 100 | Out-file ./namesonly.json*

Comment: @NeMo, try `$personalNameObjects | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 > namesonly.json`

Comment: Thanks that works. Any idea why your convertto-json works but mine doesn't? Posh accepted the syntax but it didn't actually produce anything.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @NeMo; my guess was that providing input the input _object by object_ via the _pipeline_ lessens the memory load. Passing the input objects as an array _argument_ (e.g. `ConvertTo-Json (1..10)` ) does work in principle. Note that the output will be a single JSON array, whereas your input consisted of separate JSON documents (one per line). To produce the latter, you could use `$personalNameObjects | ForEach-Object { ConvertTo-Json -Compress $_ } > namesonly.json`, but that will be much slower.