# From a 700MB json file, how do I list all the keys in Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, reflection, large-data

I tried

```
$obj = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path -LiteralPath names.json)) | ConvertFrom-Json
 
$keys = @() 
 
foreach ($key in $obj.GetEnumerator()) { 
  $keys += $key.Key 
} 
 
Write-Output $keys
```

But after over 24 hours it had not completed.

I need the key names so I can

1. Delete irrelevant info and make it smaller
2. Convert it to csv (the key names are required, otherwise PS just uses the first object and ignores keys which are not present in the first object)

The JSON is a version of this one (though 200 megs smaller): https://kaikki.org/dictionary/All%20languages%20combined/by-pos-name/kaikki_dot_org-dictionary-all-by-pos-name.json

Comment: Given the nature of your data, `$obj` will be an _array_ of `[pscustomobject]` instances. You don't need `.GetEnumerator()` to enumerate the elements of an array. The individual `[pscustomobject]` instances have _no_ `.Key` property, given that the individual JSON objects do not. What actual property are you looking for?

Comment: The file you linked is not a valid JSON file. Also `$keys += $key.Key` will reallocate array on every iteration and copy values to the new instance. It is going to be *very* slow on large arrays.

Comment: Good point re `+=`, @n0rd. The linked file is composed of _one JSON document per line_, which `ConvertFrom-Json` _can_ parse as such, _if_ the file is fed to it _line by line_, which is what `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` ensures.

Comment: @NeMo, as shown as an example in my [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77391680/45375), the `.word` property _may_ be what you're looking for: `$obj.word`. For details on why "extending" arrays with `+=` is a bad idea, as mentioned by n0rd, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).

Comment: Fyi. According to his comment on my answer, his JSON file may be a JSONL file with is certainly NOT parsed in the same way you parse a valid JSON file.

Comment: Thanks, there's other information I need (such as the sounds/IPA) not just the names themselves. The broader problem is I need to put this in a human-readable format so I can actually see what I'm looking at and pare it down further. I'm confused by comments that it's not a valid JSON file - if it were not your helpful suggestions in the previous question wouldn't have worked. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Stream the file and process each line, avoiding `Get-Content` for large files and minimizing the number of cmdlet invocations:

```
$allKeys = @{}

[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("names.json") | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = ConvertFrom-Json $_
    $obj.PSObject.Properties.Name | ForEach-Object {
        $allKeys[$_]= $true
    }
}

$uniqueKeys = $allKeys.Keys

Write-Output $uniqueKeys
```

This approach uses the .NET `ReadLines` method to efficiently stream the file and process each line.

#### I've finally finished downloading your massive JSON file.

- To process the JSON further, here's a simple extraction of "glosses" from each line:

```
$allGlosses = @()

[System.IO.File]::ReadLines("sample.json") | ForEach-Object {
    $obj = ConvertFrom-Json $_
    $obj.senses.glosses | ForEach-Object {
        $allGlosses += $_
    }
}

Write-Output $allGlosses
```

This will give you a list of glosses from each JSON object.

#### Feedback Reply:

Perhaps use a hashtable to store unique keys and avoid using `ForEach-Object` unnecessarily, and use a full path for file access:

```
$allKeys = @{}
$filePath = Resolve-Path "names.json"

foreach ($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($filePath)) {
    $obj = ConvertFrom-Json $line
    foreach ($key in $obj.PSObject.Properties.Name) {
        $allKeys[$key] = $true
    }
}

$uniqueKeys = $allKeys.Keys

Write-Output $uniqueKeys
```

This code avoids growing an array with `+=`, uses a foreach loop instead of `ForEach-Object`, and resolves the file path before using it in the .NET method.

Comment: Wait a sec. Are you telling me your JSON file is a [JSONL](https://jsonlines.org/) file?

Comment: This worked, thank you. Note I didn't create the original file. I was unaware that JSONL was a thing. But we got what we needed so thanks.

Comment: JSONL is interesting. It seemed like the way you've described data being stored. The parser would split each JSON entry at a `\n` character and then further process it as a record. I haven't played around with it much. WebSockets comes to mind..

Comment: What makes your answer useful is solving the OP's core problem: discovering all top-level property names across all objects parsed from the JSON input file.
However, what makes it problematic is the presence of three anti-patterns:

Comment: You're using a less efficient variant of the OP's own code that showcases the anti-pattern of calling a cmdlet _once for each input object_, via `ForEach-Object`, when that isn't necessary.
Another anti-pattern is to use `+=` to "grow" arrays, especially with large input sets, as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708579/45375).
The final anti-pattern is to pass only a file _name_ (or _relative path_) to a .NET method, which cannot be expected to work (robustly), given that .NET's working directory differs from PowerShell's.

Answer (score 1):

You're **already using the most efficient way (in PowerShell) to parse your line-based *JSONL* input file** (see the bottom section for an explanation).

It seems that you are simply **looking to discover the *property names*** of the `[pscustomobject]` instances that `ConvertFrom-Json` parsed the JSON documents into.

Note:

- In the following discussion, `$someObj` represents a *single* object, such as you would get with `$someObj = $obj[0]` based on your code, given that `$obj` contains a (large) *array* of objects; the sample visualizations use `$obj[0]` from the [linked file](https://kaikki.org/dictionary/All%20languages%20combined/by-pos-name/kaikki_dot_org-dictionary-all-by-pos-name.json).
- Different objects in your JSONL input file may have *different* properties. Finding a *shared set* of property names, if any, would require more effort. [suchislife's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77413365/45375) shows how to find the *union* of all distinct property names, i.e. **all *top-level* property names *across all objects***; a more concise solution would be (outputs a sorted list of property names):

  ```
  $allTopLevelPropNames = 
    [Collections.Generic.SortedSet[string]] @(
      $obj | ForEach-Object { $_.psobject.Properties.Name }
    )
  ```

The simplest way to **discover an object's *immediate* (top-level) properties** is via the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views):

```
$propNames = $someObj.psobject.Properties.Name
```

Using [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member) is another option (primarily useful for *display* output):

```
$someObj | Get-Member -Type Properties
```

However, given that **the `[pscustomobject]` instances stored in `$obj` are object *graphs*, i.e. each is a hierarchy of *nested* `[pscustomobject]`s**, you may be interested in **discovering the *hierarchy* of property names, i.e. the object *structure***:

- If you don't mind defining a *helper function*, you can use the `Get-LeafProperty` function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189034/45375), which represent a given `[pscustomobject]` as a list of *property path-value pairs*; e.g., `$someObj | Get-LeafProperty` yields something like:

  ```
  NamePath                         Value
  --------                         -----
  pos                              name
  head_templates[0].name           en-proper noun
  head_templates[0].expansion      Abib
  etymology_text                   From Hebrew אָבִיב (avív, literally “ears of barley”), hence “the season of beginning barley-crop”, because the grains start ripening at that tim…
  etymology_templates[0].name      bor
  etymology_templates[0].args.1    en
  etymology_templates[0].args.2    he
  etymology_templates[0].args.3    אָבִיב
  etymology_templates[0].args.tr   avív
  etymology_templates[0].args.lit  ears of barley
  etymology_templates[0].expansion Hebrew אָבִיב (avív, literally “ears of barley”)
  ```
- An *ad hoc* option is simply to ***re-convert to JSON*, using [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json)**, taking advantage of the fact that the resulting JSON representation is *pretty-printed by default* (opt-out requires use of `-Compress`):

  ```
  $someObj | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5
  ```

  - Note the - unfortunate -  need to specify a `-Depth` argument with a sufficiently high number of levels to serialize, so as to avoid truncation (the default depth is only `2`; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53583677/45375) for details).
- Another ad hoc option - for *display output only*, but  with less noisy output than JSON - is to use **[`Format-Custom`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-custom)**:

  ```
  $someObj | Format-Custom
  ```

  - You'll get a hierarchical display without quoting that is easy to parse visually. As with all `Format-*` cmdlets, the output is for *display* only, and not suitable for *programmatic* processing (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55174715/45375)).
  - `Format-Custom`'s default depth is `5`, so no `-Depth` argument is required in this case.
  - While usually not necessary to get a sense of the overall structure of an object graph and its property *names*,<sup>[1]</sup> note that in general you may need to (temporarily) set the [`$FormatEnumerationLimit` preference variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#formatenumerationlimit) to ensure that all elements of a *collection* (array) among the property values are visualized; by default, only *4* elements are, and omitted elements are represented as `…`.

Sample `Format-Custom` output (abridged):

```
class PSCustomObject
{
  pos = name
  head_templates = 
    [
      class PSCustomObject
      {
        name = en-proper noun
        expansion = Abib
      }
    ]
    
  etymology_text = From Hebrew אָבִיב (avív, literally “ears of barley”), hence “the season of beginning barley-crop”, because the grains start ripening at that time of year.
  etymology_templates = 
    [
      class PSCustomObject
      {
        name = bor
        args = 
          class PSCustomObject
          {
            1 = en
            2 = he
            lit = ears of barley
          }
        expansion = Hebrew אָבִיב (avív, literally “ears of barley”)
      }
    ]
    
  word = Abib
  lang = English
  lang_code = en

   …

}
```

---

Based on the properties discovered above, here's an example with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties) that creates CSV data from the input objects:

```
# Sample CSV output - limited to 10 in this example.
$obj | 
  Select-Object -First 10 -Property word, 
                                    lang, 
                                    @{ n='glosses'; e={ $_.senses.glosses } } |
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

---

###### Efficient processing of JSONL files:

[suchislife](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77413365/45375) found the proper term to describe the ***line-based* format of your JSON input data**: [**JSONL (JSON Lines format)**](https://jsonlines.org/); that is, ***each line* of your input file is a *self-contained* JSON document** (which implies that the file *as a whole* is *not* valid JSON, due to lack of an overall enclosing object or array).

**[`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) has built-in heuristics to support such input**:

- *If* the *first input object (string)* is a *self-contained JSON document*, it is parsed as such, and all subsequent lines are treated the same. Otherwise, all input lines are *collected in full*, and are *then* interpreted as JSON, *together* (i.e., as a single JSON document comprising all input lines).
- As an aside: This heuristic has potential pitfalls with respect to *empty lines* and *single-line comments* at the start - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71053689/45375).

Therefore, as shown in your question
(`[System.IO.File]::ReadLines((Convert-Path -LiteralPath names.json)) | ConvertFrom-Json`):

- **you can stream a JSONL file's lines - one by one - *directly* to `ConvertFrom-Json`**.

  - This is much more efficient than using a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call in which `ConvertFrom-Json` is invoked *once for each line*.
  - Likewise, with JSONL input `ConvertFrom-Json` streams its `[pscustomobject]` *output* objects *as they become available*, i.e. right after parsing a given input line.
- and **to perform this streaming *efficiently with a large input file*, [`[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.File.ReadLines) is (currently) needed**.

  - [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) is used to ensure that a *full* path is passed, because .NET's working directory usually *differs* from PowerShell's (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791227/45375)).
  - While the PowerShell-idiomatic [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) (without `-Raw`) works too, it is - unfortunately - much slower, because each line read is decorated with [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) properties.

    - Per [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537#issuecomment-1497770155), introducing an *opt-out* of this costly decoration via a `-NoExtendedMember` switch has been green-lit, but no one has stepped up to implement it yet (as of PowerShell 7.3.10, current as of this writing).

---

<sup>[1] However, if collection-valued properties comprise *instances of different types*, you may have to show *all* elements.</sup>